# Improving the tag wiki

Tags: feature-request, tag-wiki, reference

The tag wiki is a great idea, but it is lacking some features to make it more useful.

For example, Gordon posted an interesting ["reference" question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php-closed) with non-searchable PHP symbols (so people don't repeat the same questions over and over again). IMHO that is NaRQ but still a valuable resource. That was great material for the php tag-wiki, but it is [very messy as it is](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/php/info).

I think common questions for a particular subject, eg: "references" should be in their tag-wikis. But for that to work well, there has to be a way to better organize the tag wikis. So, I think we need:

- Better formatting for tag wikis
- Better ways to structure content:

  - An outline feature
  - Sub pages (perhaps?)

Also I think wiki material should be included in searches, and featured prominently (like Google does). eg: if I search for "sql many-to-many" and a tag-wiki reference exists, it should be seen maybe on top of the questions.

Comment: What does the current formatting for tag wikis not give you?

Comment: +1 for showing tag wiki content in search results. The tag wikis are great, but they're pretty obscured in the structure of the site.

Comment: I think we should break this up into separate requests, search support is a no-brainer ... we should support search

Comment: can you edit this so it only relates search, that way I can hand it to nick, then open a second request for the formatting and structuring ideas?

Comment: @waffles Sure, I'll do that soon enough.