# Magic wand time - what does your community need?

Tags: discussion, community-vp-questions

Continuing in my [series of questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/community-vp-questions) to you:
Last week, I heard [some great origin stories](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/367713). This week, I’d like to refocus a bit on what could be better (in your view).  I’m very curious about whether we’ll find near universal agreement or if we’ll discover that different communities have very different needs or ideas of how things “should” work.  So my question for you this week is:

- If you had a magic wand that you could wave that would let you fix ONE thing that would help your community (not the network, not the company, but the specific site community with which you most closely identify) overnight, what would you change (and why?), and what would the result look like - how would we know it was different?

This can be something technical (a site “pet peeve” - props to Mithical for suggesting as a topic), or could be something in policy, or could be the size of your mod team, or permissions of your users, or something about the environment in which you operate, or none of the above!

I hope it goes without saying that I don’t have the ability to magically “produce” technical change. While I might be able to advocate for technical solutions, I’m not committing here and now that we will build anything suggested here.  I’m just looking for ideas - and I would ask that you lean toward social or community based ideas rather than technical fixes, if possible.

- For bonus magic internet points, feel free to hazard a guess about whether your beliefs would be widely shared or whether you might be a bit of an island on this one.

---

| Community | "ONE thing" |
| --- | --- |
| Code Golf and Coding Challenges Stack Exchange | [Making all users use the Sandbox before posting a challenge on Code Golf and Coding Challenges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/367911) |
| All communities | [Changing age requirement needed to be a moderator](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/367914) |
| All communities | [Stop people from enforcing the rules without questioning and understanding their purpose.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/367915) |
| Stack Overflow |  |
| All communities | [Making vote counts visible regardless of reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/367918) |
| Code Golf and Coding Challenges Stack Exchange | [Built-in leaderboards on Code Golf](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/367922) |
| All communities | [Fix a 10 year old security vulnerability](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/367923) |
| All communities | [Time Travel! (Or at least a cautionary tale of community dynamics)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/367949) |
| Stack Overflow | [Discourage overly situational debugging questions, encourage more generally useful questions.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/367951) |
| All communities | [Convert Answer to Comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/367953) |
| Puzzling | [Better spoilers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/367956) |
|  | [Allow more syntax highlighting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/367964) |
| Interpersonal Skills |  |
| Software Engineering | [Encourage more community members on Software Engineering in curating minor issues in questions in favor of closing them](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/367974) |
| All communities | [Could we have Chat (and meta) on the sidebar?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/367982) |
|  | [Tag Hierarchies/Dependencies](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/367983) |
|  | [Decrease the limit of simultaneous hot questions from the same site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/367988) |
| Science Fiction & Fantasy | [Custom question-flow for asking story ID requests](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/367990) |
| English Language Learners | [Easy way to find credible definitions for words and idioms without leaving the site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/367996) |
|  | [Bring chat into this century](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/367997) |
| All communities | [A community advocate.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/367999) |
| TeX - LaTeX | [Restore previous "community promotion" conventions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/368003) |
|  | [Improve or officially support sandboxing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/368006) |
| Meta Stack Exchange | [Fewer off-topic questions from new users.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/368007) |
| All communities | [More capability to customise the Help Center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/368034) |
| Project Management | [It looks like you're asking a question about Scrum. Have you considered asking it on Project Management instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/368042) |
|  | [Provide more details about spoiler content without revealing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/368051) |
| All communities | [Site-specific new user onboarding](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/368053) |
|  | [Shared Drive for valuable Google spreadsheets](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/368054) |
|  | [Fix a major past mistake which has lasting effect to this day](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/368069) |
|  | [Force new users to take a quiz](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/368070) |
| Stack Overflow | [Duplicate closure should be a more rewarding experience](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/368077) |
| Role-playing Games | [Make it possible for RPG system tags to always appear first, and display them in a special color](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/368085) |
|  | [Multimedia Help Center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/368115) |
| Ask Ubuntu | [Archive feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/368125) |
| Graphic Design | [Modify the copyright release clause a bit for this site so that a stronger community could be built, a mechanism for sharing SVG files](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/368140) |
| English Language Learners | [Change the way questions are tagged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/368145) |
|  | [Tag Reform!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/368155) |
|  | [Better accessibility.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/368171) |
|  | [Allow non-bumping minor edits, but review them on /review](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/368193) |
|  | [Invite low rep user to a chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/368229) |
|  | [Retain existing users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/368248) |
| Biology | [Ability to search Species ID posts using pictures](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/368715) |
| Ask Ubuntu | [Better integration with other forms of Ubuntu documentation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/368885) |
| Code Golf and Coding Challenges Stack Exchange | [Automatic accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369756) |
| Ask Ubuntu | [Obsolete Answer Flag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369780) |

Comment: Since this is seeking input from users from all sites, it should probably be [featured].

Comment: Would be really nice if people could (and would) read (and follow) the rules of the sites they posted on. Some sites have closure rates  of 20% and more And I know that for Code Review one close reason takes up 60% of these closures....

Comment: @Vogel612'sShadow- I should have said this, but it would be great if you could put that in an answer so that people can comment on it.

Comment: I may post an answer, I'm still looking over my wishlist :). But, I just wanted to say thank you for asking this specific question. There's been a lot of "estrangement" from the communities on the network over the past few years, and this is a great first step towards fixing that

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing- thanks, that's really valuable feedback to have.  :-)

Comment: @Philippe it's not really intended as an answer, it's more of a venting thing. While the point is one that could be made in a constructive manner, I don't have the self-control necessary for that and wouldn't want to get the discussion (or more accurately this instance of the discussion) off to a terrible start.

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing if all else fails, post it all 

Comment: For me to reconsider participating on these sites ever again, [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/366449) would have to be fixed - because it is an unaddressed injustice and a stain on the company's conscience, for one, but also because it getting fixed would indicate that some dysfunctional patterns within the company (which could become detrimental to volunteers again) might actually have changed

Comment: @Pekka you may be interested in [this answer here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/368069/165773)

Comment: Could we get a list of the answer headers in the question so one does not need to scroll so much?

Comment: @joojaa was it done before? Won't do it without OP telling it is OK.

Comment: @ShadowWizardWearingMaskV2 no objection.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Let's Plan the Second Iteration of the Stack Exchange Quality Project!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/285889/lets-plan-the-second-iteration-of-the-stack-exchange-quality-project)

Comment: Post seeking input from the Ask Ubuntu community: https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/19683

Comment: @joojaa Done! Please do any necessary edits :)

Answer (score 57):

### Making vote counts visible regardless of reputation

According to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/69854/388685), the main reason viewing vote count is restricted by rep is because it's costly on the server side. It'd probably take a bit of work, but I'm sure it'd be possible to optimize things a bit so that anyone who has an account can view vote counts.

This isn't quite as important on main sites, but on meta and per-site metas it's often important to be able to see the vote breakdown. On CGCC, for example, a lot of our rules are based on voting on meta questions and answers, so not being able to see vote breakdowns makes it difficult for a new user to determine if something meets the requirements to be a valid answer or not.

Even if an answer has +10 score, without being able to see the vote breakdown you have no way to know if 10 people found an answer to be incredibly useful, or 1000 found it to be helpful and 990 did not.

This is definitely more a smaller issue, but it'd be nice if newer users (or established users on other sites) wouldn't have to resort to workarounds like userscripts to be able to see vote breakdowns.

Comment: I [asked for this in 2016](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/286897/275609) and was told performance was still an issue then.

Comment: @xnor I'm not asking specifically for the counts to be shown by default, just for the rep requirement to be lowered or removed, which I think would be much better performance-wise.

Comment: If vote counts should be restricted, I'd be at least happy if there was an association bonus-like way to unlock them. It's quite annoying being very used to a feature on one stack and not being allowed to use it on another. Yes, rep does mean there is some measure of trust to a user, but I don't see why you should be trusted to see the vote counts separately on each individual stack.

Comment: I agree; the part that makes this even sillier is that the information is publicly accessible through SEDE and the API anyway. There's [a userscript](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts#fetch-vote-counts-again) that gives you the functionality on any Stack site, it just feels weird for it to require a seemingly arbitrary 1,000 rep.

Comment: SEDE and the API are all very well for technical users -- what about the non-technical users? If you're trying to fix a problem on meta sites (which I agree exists) why not ask for e.g. a Poll mechanism -- it's long been the fact that shoehorning what is effectively 'polling' into a Q&A format does not work well. I'd make an answer out of this but it isn't the biggest issue for 'my' site.

Comment: I see one issue with this, you need some site specific experience to understand the logic behind vote counts. It can be overwhelming enough to get to 1k, I don't know how far seeing vote counts might be TMI before 1k. An argument can also be made that it motives users between the 500 rep review queue privilege and the 2k edit privilege.

Comment: And if performance is still an issue, can we at least [allow users to see vote counts on their own posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/328135/please-re-consider-enabling-low-rep-users-to-see-individual-up-down-votes-on-the)

Comment: ["View Vote totals" without 1000 rep](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/view-vote-totals-without/oibfliilcglieepgkdkahpfiiigdijdd?hl=en) ?

Answer (score 52):

**Hi, we're special!**

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zCNxC.png) is what the front page of IPS looks like to someone that doesn't have a profile there. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oonF0.png) is what it looks like after you've made a profile and log in. And what you end up seeing after finding us on HNQ: [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GD8gk.png) or [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYQwy.png) depending on whether you're logged in. The 'Questions' page too, where people are likely to end up browsing other questions: it looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yU2DK.png).

Let me add some more screenshots to compare those with: [A forum](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDXEs.png), one of the [Facebook groups I'm in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AnyQb.png), and a not so-random [subreddit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kcSJ4.png).

Spot the differences. Both that Facebook group and that subreddit have a box in their right sidebar with rules and information about the thing you're looking at. All IPS gets is a big black banner with some text. Our meta (does a newbie know what meta is?), chat, our help center... All the things that contain information about what makes our site just a little bit different from others: they're all hidden away behind [this button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8iAvW.png).

As for the forum post I threw in there: "Closed" behind a question doesn't immediately make it clear that this is because the question is unsuitable for the site. On that forum I screenshotted, for example, 'Closed' means as much as 'I'm not looking for reactions right now'. If your post was problematic, it would've been deleted by moderators/admins. But for a new user to SE, there is no place that explains what 'closed' means (until they open the question), they just see a list of titles and assume they can ask about similar things.

Do you think a total newbie would want to know who the newest valued associates are, or what the site statistics are? That they're immediately looking for tags to watch, or to create a free team? Or would it perhaps be better to give each site a part of that right sidebar, where they can explain "Hey, if you're thinking of asking a question here, look at this and this. If you want to answer, here's your relevant info! Also, don't use our comments to argue or write answers in". I want that box, similar to what my Facebooks groups and some not-so-random subreddits have. I want to have the ability to shove it in people's faces: **Hi, we're special, and this is what makes us different from other sites you may be used to!**.

Comment: A million times this, yes!

Comment: Code golf also had this problem, but recently, we got [a nice box in the top right corner](https://i.imgur.com/I28pYW2.png). Maybe you can get one too.

Comment: @Adám The one on Code Golf is a nice example of what that could look like, but I was really thinking something that can be edited by the moderators on the site itself though, something a bit more flexible than having to depend on SE devs to [make/update](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/22161/78230) such a box :)

Comment: [Law](https://law.stackexchange.com/), [MiYodeya](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/), and [Christianity](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/) all have one, that I know of. Might be good to check with the mods of those sites how they got it? Probably a [tag:status-review] on their meta sites?

Comment: Also MSE has an FAQ... wonder if it would be possible to get an FAQ to your meta questions, where the title is a rule, and the link gives context?

Comment: @LShaver IPS already has a FAQ. That post is buried on our meta, and the only way to get it linked on main is by keeping it featured, which only shows the title and no other context. A box would allow for a lot more context, really think something like that Facebook screenshot. I don't mind if it collapses and someone can press 'show more'. But it needs to be front and center, and something moderators can do without having to status-review anything and wait for SE (the current sites with disclaimers had to ask SE, some before the current status-review process was in place)

Comment: @Tinkeringbell I love this. We have 176 unique communities on this platform. Let's celebrate and highlight that more. :)

Comment: Similar to Rosie, I really like this too. Maybe we can get it done - I shall poke around.

Comment: @CesarM I'm not sure what you're planning to do after poking around but... This answer really is just a write-up of a 'shower-thought', not a fully thought-out feature request, I never thought about whether this could have any downsides, for example. As an answer to this question, it's also a bit more hidden than a proper feature request would ever have been, and as such it may very well be that people who absolutely don't want this or see serious downsides to it have never seen it. If there are such people, they aren't going to love SE for just shoving a box like this in their faces, I guess.

Comment: @Tinkeringbell oh! Sorry! By Poking around I meant socializing the idea internally and seeing what people think. I like it, but it's not something we have planned or even discussed, so it starts at discussing it with different folks and seeing how it goes. If there's interest/anything actually concrete I'll update and it would go through our normal feedback collection/development process: as in, we would give a chance for people to give thoughts before launching it. For now, just talking!

Comment: @CesarM Pfew! Glad to hear that :)

Comment: It is great. It is worth noting that for quite a lot of years all sites [had this box](https://nickberardi.com/content/images/2008/08/stackoverflow1.png).

Answer (score 48):

### Fix a 10 year old [security vulnerability](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55665/allowing-images-from-external-sources-opens-doors-to-serious-security-exploits)

You can add images from any source in a post (or in chat). This allows things like:

- Determining the IP addresses of specific chat users or (with less accuracy) highly active users on main

  - This allows tracking which questions they view, which chat transcripts they open, and more
- Gaming the Announcer-class badges
- Making it appear to network administrators that people on school or work computers are navigating to porn sites
- Phishing passwords from people using old browsers
- Silently taking advantage of certain CORS vulnerabilities in other sites
- Freezing users' browsers with specially crafted SVGs
- Using advertising links to make money

Additionally, after these "images" (usually not actually images) are removed from an offending post, one can link to the revision page, which appears trustworthy but still contains the payload.

Comment: How would this help fix one specific community (like Philippe asks for in the question)?

Comment: @EkadhSingh It's admittedly not as focused on one specific community, but it's definitely something that many members of the community of the site that I spend most of my time on have agreed is concerning. From what I can tell this falls under the "pet peeve" section of the question.

Comment: Is this the issue that killed Twitter oneboxing in chat?

Comment: Its a different security issue IIRC :D

Comment: I would be unhappy if we couldn't use SVG images. Maybe they could be supported via a variant of [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/4014959).

Comment: @PM2Ring I definitely don't think disabling SVGs is the right solution, but requiring hosting through a trusted source is a good start, and I'd imagine some sort of restriction for ridiculously large SVGs (if things like imgur don't already have any) could probably be implemented on top of that without too many issues.

Comment: Yes, a trusted host would be ideal. AFAIK, Imgur still doesn't support SVG. https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/92568/334566 I mostly link to Wikimedia SVGs, but I occasionally link to my own creations, which I host as GitHub Gists.

Answer (score 48):

### Duplicate closure should be a more rewarding experience

The main community I use is Stack Overflow. We have more than a decade worth of questions - *chances are* that most simple queries are answered. Yet we get them again and again. We are drowning in duplicates. Some show up *multiple times a day*.

There are multiple issues with closing duplicates that make it a chore and not even viewed in good light.

#### Closure seen as bad

Duplicates are *closed* and many users seem to think that closure is somehow bad. There are two misconceptions here, in fact:

- closure is *not* bad. It is supposed to be a temporary state until the question is improved. It is quite neutral, not any sort of judgment on the user as a person or driven by malice.
- Duplicates are *a type of answer*. This discrepancy is jarring because dupe closures are still closures. Yet, we close as dupes not as a temporary state<sup>1</sup> but to immediately give access to answers. In some cases, the answers have been curated and improved for *years*.

These misconceptions put people off.

In the ideal magical world of my fantasy, duplicate closure would not be presented as "closure" but re-framed as a way of answering.

<sup>1</sup> Unless the duplicate was wrong. But we do not aim to close against the wrong target.

---

#### Question askers do not cooperate

The misconceptions do agitate a lot of them. This leads to some fighting the duplicate closures. Here are some of the common arguments:

- The title does not match. But we do not close based on title but answers.
- The top answer does not help. Again, we close because of *all* answers, not just the top one.
- The duplicate does not work for their code. *Very* often this is because their code uses *different names* - it is not `foo` it is `bar`. Or values - not `42` it is `215`. And that is it - everything is the same.

We close as duplicates to give access to ready-made answers instead of having to wait. Having to then further spend time *convincing* people that yes, this is the answer but you have to *maybe* modify slightly or *maybe* even read further down is frankly exhausting.

Not *all* question askers disagree or fight the dupe closures. However, I seriously sometimes avoid closure and just leave it because I do not feel I have the mental fortitude to start explaining yet again why a would answer something.

In my imagination I picture question askers being *happy* they are linked to a high-quality existing resource. Because they recognize that it does solve their problem.

---

#### Question answerers do not cooperate

Another reason to close as duplicates is to consolidate all knowledge in one place. This only works if all the knowledge *is* in one place.

Very often, however, we get answers to duplicate questions. Sometimes *many*. A common and simple enough question can rack up 5+ answers by the time it is closed.

Sometimes, duplicates are not even closed. It is *extremely* frustrating to start searching for a duplicate and find 3-4 different questions that are all fundamentally the same but you cannot really choose any one of them because all are open and all have different answers.

Gold badge closure power helps *a bit* but not everybody has that.

In my dreams, people are *motivated* to find or vote for a duplicate instead of answering.

---

#### Searching for the correct dupe target is not very pleasant

I cannot entirely blame people for answering duplicates. Having to look for existing answers is a literal thankless task. The vast majority of the time, at least.

Some duplicates are easier to find. Others take more time. Regardless of the type, I personally start to get exhausted after having to look for a dozen duplicates in a row. It feels like I am just a personalized search assistant. I imagine others might have even less of a tolerance to that.

A simple answer is *very* tempting. It might be easier to write one than find the correct duplicate target. Also, answers get upvotes, comments, and reputation in general. Finding a duplicate gives you either nothing or frustration.

With some imaginary powder, I would make it so somehow proposing duplicates has some sort of reward. Some *incentive* to do it rather than just because consolidated knowledge is how what we want of Stack Overflow. It will help mitigate some of the dissatisfaction related to this.

---

#### Amount of incoming questions is high

This might be a personal thing but what I also find exhausting is just how fast questions are coming in. At more busy hours, there might be 10 questions a minute. At less busy hours maybe 1 question a minute. Normally, it is somewhere in between.

In the time I spend evaluating few candidate questions to see which most closely matches as a duplicate target... there may be another 30-50 new questions added. A lot of them asking things that were already asked years ago.

That is only about the tags I monitor. At least in that corner of Stack Overflow, it seems impossible to keep up. We need to have more people curating given the number of questions we get.

Hopefully, all these magical transformations will make it *easier* for users to find an answer to their questions. Which will reduce the tide of new duplicates that come in. At least a bit.

---

With a magic wand, I would like to make the duplicate closure more pleasant for *everybody* involved. Close voters, answerers, as well as question authors. I just hope there is magic strong enough to do that.

Comment: This is an excellent answer (+1). If I come across any magic which is strong enough to do any part of what you're requesting, I'll certainly let you know :-) .

Comment: I really like the "duplicates are not a closure" idea. Perhaps rather than just closing the question and saying "go over there" it could result in the answers appearing under the question that has been marked as a duplicate. Not quite a merge, but not quite alone either. It would mean that the person asking the question gets all the help right away instead of that jarring feeling you just told them to go somewhere else. Of course leaving the question locked to answers is good, and the answer box should be replaced with a "go to the original to post an answer" info box.

Comment: I would add that for old questions finding a dupe in most cases doesn't even give you an accepted flag, because the queue is drowning in them and they're mostly never seen by other people. I've read multiple stats posts, but the flagging stats for my (and OP's) use case is the opposite.

Comment: @EvgenKo423 yes, trying to CV an old post is pretty hard, I agree. It helps if you get a gold badge hammer :) That finally allows you to do something about old questions. But... also means that you have to deal with the old questions which weren't dupe closed and most likely spawned multiple copies :( Just trying to research all the potential dupes is a chore. Sometimes it's unsolvable because there are two or even more competing questions *all* with good answers. Nothing you can easily pick a clear winner of.

Answer (score 42):

## Could we have Chat (and meta) on the sidebar?

This is kinda a request that goes across communities, but also is about communities (Very [Zathras](https://babylon5.fandom.com/wiki/Zathras), I know).

In the old days, chat was a "first class" citizen of the network, sharing a top bar with the main site and meta. Both (per site) meta and Chat are second class citizens compared to Teams. It would be very nice to consider having per site meta and chat represented on the left bar - as our second and third spaces.

People don't really find meta (or end up here by accident) or chat as easily as they did, and that is detrimental to the vibrancy of the respective spaces for each community.

Comment: I agree.  I really think that if we're going to have it, we should expose it.  I don't like "hidden" features, because that creates exclusive "in" groups (those in the know).

Comment: I only found chat by literally clicking every kind of link I could find on the homepage to figure out where it went. Would love for that process to be easier :)

Comment: Yep, I honestly am barely even aware that Chat exists, other than when people refer to it in Meta posts sometimes. (Then again, for me in my timezone, I have never found Chat at all useful in the few times I have tried it.)

Answer (score 41):

### Improve or officially support sandboxing

Code Golf is probably the site with the biggest need for this feature, though other sites like Worldbuilding have sandboxes as well.

Currently, sandboxes are just meta questions. Answers are drafts, and comments and votes are used for feedback. CGCC's sandbox currently has over 3000 answers, and the limitations of this system have become apparent:

- It's difficult to review drafts, and often unrewarding
- It's difficult to get people to notice sandbox posts, so they need to be regularly advertised in chat
- This means that new users' posts can sometimes slip past and receive no feedback, even when they do everything right and use the sandbox as requested
- It's difficult to get new users to notice or use the sandbox, when they're the ones who it would likely be most helpful for

Despite almost every new user being requested to use the sandbox in the tour, welcome modal, ask question guidance, and most reviewers' welcome comments, we still get plenty of questions which are either off-topic or lacking the necessary clarity or objectivity that the site requires.

I don't have any specific solution in mind, because I don't know how much work these would take or how much work SE would be capable of putting in. But, ranging from the simplest to the most effective, here are some ideas:

- Add a link next to the "ask question" button, taking you to the sandbox
- Add a feature where a meta question can be marked as an official sandbox (maybe a mod-only [sandbox](/questions/tagged/sandbox) tag), which could add various things:

  - Disabling the "there are already more than 30 answers" pop-up
  - Sorting by active by default, regardless of the user's sort order on the rest of meta
  - Linking to the sandbox (in a very obvious way) in various highly visible places, such as the sidebar and review tab of the ask question page
  - A way to show the most recent few drafts somewhere visible, like the sidebar, to encourage reviewing
  - A way to quickly migrate questions to and from the sandbox
- Add an official solution for sandboxing, like a sandbox subdomain or something like collectives

Any solution that would have a meaningful impact would probably take a lot of work for SE, but it would be immensely appreciated on sites where sandboxing is encouraged, and it would likely decrease the number of closed or negatively voted questions on sites like CGCC *massively*.

Comment: It might be worth thinking about what other sites need sandboxes too - y'all might not be the only one.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I definitely think the idea of sandboxing could work with a lot of other sites, and the main problems with its adoption are likely the same ones CGCC struggles with. I think a highly visible sandbox that makes posting drafts (and reviewing them) easy would help a lot with that.

Comment: This would indeed be very useful compared to most of the other suggestions here!

Answer (score 37):

#### Stack Overflow: Discourage overly situational debugging questions, encourage more generally useful questions.

This likely means less focus (especially by high-rep users) on **if the asker has put in enough effort to *deserve* a solution** and more focus on **whether the question is a specific, clear programming problem.**

As Shog9 puts better than I ever could, the only question we should be asking about effort is ["has the asker put enough thought into the problem to formulate a clear, specific question?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260909/208273)

This means no more comments that are basically just ["What have you tried so far?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/172760/165261) (which you can still post as long as you add "so far") or "Stack Overflow is not a free code-writing service" ([it is](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/408565/208273)).

Such a strong focus on problem-solving effort emphasizes debugging questions so specific to the asker's situation that they're unlikely to be of use to anyone other than the original asker (Shog9's above-linked answer, again, explains this better than I can).  Frequently, such debugging questions technically comply with all the rules, get answered, the answerer gets some rep, and then the question is never seen again by anyone who finds it useful for the rest of eternity.

Answer (score 37):

This is something that recently came up over on [SFF](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour) as it is very similar to one of the questions (#9) asked in the election questionnaire. [In my answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/election/5?tab=election#post-249965) I mentioned new user onboarding. However, this is something that looks to be being worked on at the moment and some good steps have been taken there so I won't focus on that here. I'm sure @Catija will also be glad that I'm not going to ask about site theming this time around!

What I do want to focus on is something a bit more specific to SFF though not solely applicable there:

#### Tag Hierarchies/Dependencies

Many sites in practice employ [Tag Hierarchies](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/45438/278659), meaning that every question with *this* tag must also have *that* tag.

- On SFF, for example, all [avengers-endgame] questions should be tagged with [marvel-cinematic-universe] and in turn all [marvel-cinematic-universe] questions should also have the [marvel] tag. This means if you're asking a question on a specific [MCU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marvel_Cinematic_Universe) film, you need 3 tags by default out of the 5 maximum. See [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4860/58193) and [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7923/58193) for example, and there's a [long-standing feature request](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4891/58193) for tag hierarchies.
- On [Literature](https://literature.stackexchange.com/tour), similarly, all [nineteen-eighty-four] questions should be tagged with [george-orwell], and the same for any story with a known author, while all [war-and-peace] questions should be tagged with [leo-tolstoy] and [russian-literature]. This means if you're asking a question on a Russian novel, you need 3 tags by default out of the 5 maximum. The site has a clear, consistent, and rigid tagging system, but the 5-tag limit is often a problem.
- On [Puzzling](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour), again, all [geometry] questions should be tagged with [mathematics], and all [sudoku] questions should be tagged with [grid-deduction] and [logical-deduction]. (Actual tagging isn't fully consistent with these policies, but a few users are working on it slowly.) This has [come up](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2875/5373) a few [times](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5565/5373) on meta, and tag hierarchies have been [requested](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3058/5373) again.
- On [M&TV](https://movies.stackexchange.com/tour) they have something similar to us on SFF with universe/franchise tags and specific work tags. It is also likely applicable to the more technical sites where library tags and version tags probably want the main language tag all the time: the main meta feature request linked above refers mainly to SO.

In short, we need a way to make it easier to group tags together that rely on each other: something more automatic than just writing "please use this tag together with this other tag" in the wiki excerpt and then a lot of editing when new users inevitably fail to notice or read the wiki.

The change here would essentially mean that we could mark tags as dependant on one another and so if a question is tagged with Tag A it will also always be tagged with Tab B, C, etc.

This might mean a change in the number of tags allowed on a post as well, or that the higher level tags are not shown on the question but are linked to it in some other way, but the posts will still be discoverable through those higher level tags too.

Comment: FWIW changing the way privileges are awarded to come from an action based system rather than a rep based system is something I've spoken about [on](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/58631?m=49145922#49145922) and [off](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/51694986#51694986) over the years but that's at a system level rather than community level and might be out of scope for this discussion. It would also be a major overhaul of the way the core system works.

Comment: I got permission from you to edit this answer, hope it isn't too much :-) I was already drafting an answer along the same lines, so I edited yours to avoid redundancy.

Comment: This would also be used (to a lesser extent) on Code Golf with the [math] tag. We don't have any requirements to use tags with it, but if a challenge is tagged with [math], it likely has others such as [arithmetic], [number-theory], [sequence] etc.

Comment: Tag taxonomy is something that I find really interesting.  I'm always amazed and the level of thought that goes into it - and most people never appreciate it, but it's so important.  Thanks for bringing this up.

Comment: +1000 !!! Tag hierarchies would be extremely helpful on a lot of sites! Also, PhysicsOverflow (which is not in the SE network) already has this implemented, so it can't be ***too*** hard. @Philippe I love this suggestion!

Comment: We could use this on Genealogy to clarify our tagging significantly

Comment: Oh yes, Code Review could definitely use this for language tags. We'd also like a group of tags that are used like [tag:discussion] and [tag:bug]. A group of which one tag must be selected before posting (again, for language tags). Code is always written in a language, we don't accept pseudo-code questions.

Comment: I requested something similar which would be fixed with tag hierarchies on [CR meta](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9150), but was shot down. We have language tags which _must_ be applied to questions, and language version tags which _can_ be applied to questions. [python-3.x] alone is not a 'valid tagging scheme'. It'd be so nice to be able to mark all our game tags as [game] children and all our algorithms tags as [algorithm] children. We can't manually fix this because a {game} using {algorithm} in {language version} would go over the tag limit!

Comment: @Philippe yes, it's important. Please, keep it flat and make people accept that hierarchies are just a solution looking for a problem. Change "tags" to mean "categories" as the help center calls it and make it more explicit that they should be unambiguous and well defined.

Comment: "every question with this tag must also have that tag" I feel you are using tags wrong: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/18879/376358 Point 1: <Each tag should stand on its own>

Comment: @Federico I feel you've misunderstood the point that's being made there: _"if a tag only makes sense when used in a group with other tags, it's wrong"_ - the tags ___do___ make sense on their own. It's just that those questions are also in scope to the broader tag(s) and so need those as well.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot I see what you mean

Comment: Couldn't a system not automatically complete the tag list if the relation between the tags is that strict? If tag A always requires tag B then simply add B automatically as soon as A is added.

Comment: Mentioning in case anyone wants to see one live implementation: Codidact has had tag hierarchies for some time now.

Answer (score 32):

#### Stop people from enforcing the rules without questioning and understanding their purpose.

We have a lot of rules here, and that is a good thing most of the time. But the rules tend to take on a life of their own, independent of the purpose they used to serve. Most of our rules boil down to ensuring that people are civil and that the content meets a certain quality threshold. The specific rules are simply patterns we saw that indicated problems.

This can get to a point where people simply match patterns and act on anything that matches that pattern, no matter if the content actually presents a problem or not. This is in part due to some of our rules being inherently difficult to judge, but my impression is that in the end we always end up with more of a "letter of the law" enforcement than any true understanding of the purpose of our rules.

Half of this problem are popular, but inherently problematic rules like those against homework questions. They're very easy to overapply to posts that are not a quality problem. But you can misuse most of our other rules as well.

This is not about a single site, but about two that I feel attached to. How much of an issue this is probably depends quite heavily on the dynamics of the community and the topic, some topics are inherently more difficult to deal with.

Comment: No, WIKIPEDIA has a lot of rules:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:List_of_policies_and_guidelines.   We are but babes compared to that particular mess (but your point is valid, nonetheless)

Comment: Separate SE sites interpret the rules different ways.  On Bicycles we're pretty forgiving about grey-area posts, but other SE sites are hard-nosed and delete-happy.   Upshot - not every site is the same, and being pulled up for not enacting the rules the same as another site is meh.

Comment: @Philippe I don't know much about the admin side of Wikipedia, but I think the best analogue of Mad Scientist's excellent point here would be [this Wikipedia rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Ignore_all_rules) (hat-tip [Shog9](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/124915/278659) for the link), which we don't *explicitly* have as a principle here on SE. I'd be in favour of codifying something like that in the help centre, which might help to address the issue that MS raises.

Comment: Ah, @Randal'Thor.  You mean WP:IAR (Ignore All Rules) right?  I can opine at great length on that one, but my feeling has consistently been that it's analogous to the Queen refusing royal assent.  It's a safety valve that you hope that you never need to use.  Ive seen IAR invoked maybe twice, legitimately, on Wikipedia (and that's in 10 years).  I invoked it once myself, and was wrong (I failed to consider some things - I was younger and stupid(er).)  It's a hard one, & in my opinion it's a great statement of philosophy, but it needs to be behind glass with a red "in case of emergency" hammer.

Comment: @Philippe And here my ignorance of the Wikipedia admin world emerges :-) I didn't realise that over there it's a rule so strictly defined as to need being "invoked". In the SE context, I was thinking of it more as a philosophical point to include somewhere in the help centre, to remind some over-enthusiastic appliers of letters of rules that sometimes it's better to consider what's best for the site than to blindly apply written policies.

Comment: As a specific example: SFF meta has long had RIP posts when famous writers or actors die; some people said that's not what meta is for, we had a big discussion, and Shog said essentially "meta is for whatever you want it to be for, is this causing any actual problem?" There's a case where it might've been helpful if mods could've pointed to a clear principle of "don't blindly apply rules if there's no actual problem to be solved". Of course you have more experience of what actually happens when such a principle exists. Would be an interesting thing to discuss at more length sometime.

Comment: In my experience as a casual Wikipedia editor, mostly watching other people from the sidelines, whenever IAR gets invoked, it nearly always results in much argumentation and debate over whether it was appropriate to do so, whether the rule being ignored is even legitimate in the first place, whether the person invoking IAR is being "disruptive," etc. It's always a drama magnet and pretty much never results in everyone going "Oh, well that's OK then."

Comment: @Kevin, that’s exactly correct. That’s why I make a big deal out of iar being used legitimately. I’ve seen it invoked a lot, but very rarely correctly.

Answer (score 32):

This is a short one:

#### Bring chat into this century

Comment: I mean, the site was created in 2008, so chat was definitely created in this century... this decade though, that'd be nice. :D

Comment: Luuklag's not totally wrong though: if I build a model T Ford today, it's still of the last century.  :).  The interface looks old, and it's missing modern-appearing skinning, for instance.

Comment: @Philippe and stickers! ;)

Comment: A critical factor here is tech debt. Chat going the way of the mobile app is going to have a pretty detrimental impact for many of us

Comment: Chat on mobile is still atrocious. If it's redone, make sure mobile isn't forgotten.

Comment: Yes, @JourneymanGeek, theres almost no question that chat will need to be reworked.  There are issues with it on .net, and it’s a heavy lift to get it pulled up to modern standards.  And mast, one of the linchpins of my pitch when people ask me what I want to accomplish here… is mobile.  we won’t be ignoring that.

Comment: If there's a rebuild - an API would be a welcome part of that. There's a *ton* of community built resources that rely on somewhat jerryrigged bots that would benefit/need work when that happens

Comment: You mean all visuals are flat and huge (thanks God SE still has at least some volume in its design and reasonable sizes!...), messages with a big padding, on different sides of a window, emoticons with indistinguishable emotions (still nobody have beaten the Skype or ICQ ones...), stickers with even more indistinguishable emotions or meaning in general??... **Please, NO!!** I see nothing good made in web design in the past 5-10 years. I'd rather bring most of the things into the previous century... **TL;DR: Please, be conservative with what you're gonna do!**

Comment: As a possible voice of disagreement: I still find SE chat the most useful of all the chat tools I have to use. That includes Slack, Discord, Teams, Signal, Wire, Messenger and others. SE chat wins hands down. So if modernising it means making it anything like those others, please don't!

Answer (score 30):

### Better spoilers

The site I started on, [Puzzling](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/), has a *lot* of spoilers. Many (if not most) answers have a significant amount of content in spoilers, and many questions have a hint (or hints) in spoilers. That's the site culture. It comes with how we've tried to force the SE Q&A model to fit a puzzle-solving site.

Given that, it would be wonderful for spoilers to be improved. There are two big things:

- [Make spoilers accessible to keyboard-only users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/301971/spoilers-are-inaccessible-to-keyboard-only-users)
- Better support for Markdown in spoilers: [tables](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116613/spoilers-dont-support-block-formatting-and-so-dont-format-well), but also [everything else](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116613/spoilers-dont-support-block-formatting-and-so-dont-format-well) (since most people aren't going to discover the hack of using HTML instead of Markdown).

All that content that Puzzling has in spoilers could benefit from better, easier formatting; people are reduced to using funky hacks or just giving up on proper formatting altogether. The times that I've had to help someone figure out how to spoiler code, or explain that tables don't work, or fix up a post with an apologetic "I'm new and can't figure out the spoiler formatting" etc. are numerous. And making spoilers more accessible seems like a no-brainer (given a magic wand - I'm sure it's more complicated behind-the-scenes).

For something that combines both of these bullet points, take my crusade for Markdown table conversion. I have an [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/puzzling/query/edit/1357847) to find posts which have MathJax tables, so that I can edit them into Markdown ones to [improve accessibility](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11370/are-markdown-tables-superior-to-mathjax-arrays-for-accessibility). But... a lot of the tables I find are inside spoilers, and I can't fix those. Markdown tables simply don't work in spoilers, and even if they did, my target audience of vision-impaired-folks wouldn't be able to get to them anyways (assuming they're keyboard-only).

So given a magic wand, I would give my community better spoilers.

Comment: This is one that I haven't heard come up before.  Thanks!

Answer (score 30):

**More capability to customise the Help Center**

The elements of the Help Center that moderators can customise on behalf of their community are quite limited and limiting. The fixed elements are all about the working of the SE 'engine' and there isn't really enough 'space' to talk about the workings of the specific community, especially the community-specific expectations/aspirations for good questions and answers.

Yes, we can include useful guidance that fits naturally in the current structure, such as what is on- and off-topic, but there's other stuff we have either to shoehorn under a irrelevant topic -- making the specific information hard to find, and making that topic (What topics can I ask about here?) longer and longer and less likely to be read.

And yes, we can point to Meta questions but I don't believe Meta questions are a good means of communicating with new users -- the format is confusing to them. Why is it a question? Does that mean it isn't a policy? Why isn't this in the Help Center anyway -- does that mean it's less important?

Give us the ability to have sub-pages in the Help Center -- I won't try to design the structure here, but stuff hanging off 'how to ask a good question' and 'how to write a good answer' would be a start. And somewhere we could put our specific privacy guidance, guidance for including images of sources, guidance for asking for software recommendations, guidance on 'lookup requests', ... All the stuff that is current community policy that we expect/prefer askers and answerers to take into account. If nothing else, it should help improve the experience for newcomers and maybe that will make them stick around -- we have too many hit and run questions and we need to convert some of those into community members not drive-by posters.

Comment: Agreed, why /help/on-topic is editable but /help/dont-ask isn't is beyond me initially. And /help/how-to-answer should also be editable. On a similar note parts of the Tour would benefit from it and that expanding to cover answering more.

Comment: Agreed; new users shouldn't have to go on a safari to figure out how to format their first post on a given site... Right now, the only way to know what's on topic for sure or how certain post types should be written in some cases is to dive into the site's Meta, which isn't ideal, and is kinda hidden for anyone not familiar with Stack Exchange.

Comment: @zcoop98 Plus Meta can be intimidating (even more so these days with Mods and Staff announced in big bold orange and blue).  When I venture to other sites (which I do) I stay well clear of their Metas, so I can't blame new users for not venturing into 'ours'.

Comment: Candidates for your list: guidance for homework questions, guidance for conceptual questions ([big picture](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/big-picture)), and guidance for [big-list](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/big-list) questions

Comment: @P.Mort.-forgotClayShirky_q Not things that are a problem for genealogy.se but relevant in the bigger picture, yes.

Comment: Yeah, the onboarding experience, quite frankly, needs some work.  That's really high up on my list.

Answer (score 29):

For the SO community, more people willing to take action rather than just leaving comments.

If a question requires a dozen comments to eventually dig out all of the information required to answer it, it should have been closed in the first place until the op makes the necessary adjustments to avoid people posting guesses as answers. Ideally this would cut down on answered dupes and allow us to more effectively route users to time-tested answers.

A few potential options:

- Open up close/reopen voting sooner for high-traffic sites to reflect the fact that the majority of users are sub 3k
- Open up privileges based on actions rather than (or alternatively/in addition to) reputation
- Some just-in-time info when a comment discussion is detected to suggest improving/editing the question and/or closing
- Mind Control/Mass Hypnotism
- Artificial Intelligence

I am aware that users that are sub 3k can *flag* posts for closure, but the UI for this is confusing. It should instead follow an identical workflow to closing questions rather than being hidden within the flag dialog. My goal would be better informing users of the tools that help keep this place functional earlier rather than it feeling so adversarial until they've been here long enough to realize why things are the way they are by empowering them with the very tools we're using. You're far more likely to pay attention to a privilege you've earned than one you were introduced to as preventing you from getting the help you need.

Comment: I'd add to this "reducing the stigma surrounding having a question closed or marked as duplicate" too (I might spin this idea into its own answer tbh). I feel that it would be hard to increase the amount of general and duplicate closures if new users continue to deeply dread closures and see them as a kiss of death rather than simply a chance for improvement. We as a community can probably improve our messaging in this regard, but design and onboarding changes would help too.

Comment: I'm a big proponent of rethinking how we award privileges - while I know that not everyone understands how to effectively close or edit a post early on, I also don't think it makes sense to force people who have shown that they can do so effectively to earn the rep - and, well... not everyone who earns the rep knows how to use the privileges, either... that said, I'm sorry to say that we're not planning anything in the future along the lines of your fourth bullet.

Comment: @Catija Oh good, that means the fifth is still on the table

Comment: Pretty sure she meant that the FIFTH was off the table.  I'm actively working on the fourth.

Comment: @Philippe Maybe you should focus on the fifth instead. Seems much more practical in the long run :P

Comment: Yeah, well, I like to think big.  Out of the box, we call it.

Comment: Hey Kevin! Can you please make the necessary edit in the row which is related to your answer (Stack Overflow row) in the [table in the question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/367906/3)?

Answer (score 28):

### RPG.SE: Make it possible for RPG system tags to always appear first, and display them in a special color

There are two features I think [RPG.SE](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/) would really benefit from (that would likely also benefit other sites on the Stack Exchange network), and they're both summarized well in existing feature requests on our Meta:

- [Make it possible for certain tags (like game tags) to always appear first](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8366/33569)
- [Can we color system tags to emphasize that they're different and "more meaningful"?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8702/33569)

Basically, on RPG.SE, most questions (though not all) are primarily asking about a particular role-playing game system, and often a specific edition of that system - whether they're asking about the rules, or a problem they've encountered, or a group-dynamic issue. This is generally reflected by our tag system, so whatever system a user is asking about, there'll usually be a tag on the question to indicate it.

The name of the first tag on a question appears before the question title in the title of your tab/browser (when viewing the question), and in Google search results. In addition, the system/edition tag is often an important signal to users to help them judge whether they have the relevant expertise to answer the question.

Since D&D is a popular game, a D&D edition tag will almost always be the first tag listed on a D&D-related question... But there are thousands of other RPGs out there, and most of them aren't so lucky.

Say there's a question about the *Lancer* RPG. Because there aren't very many questions about Lancer on the site, then if other tags (e.g. [weapons](/questions/tagged/weapons)) are added to the question, they take up the first spot in the question's tags instead - meaning we have to either intentionally avoid adding a useful/relevant tag to the question, or cause the relevant RPG system to not be listed in search results/page titles.

Making it so certain tags can be designated to always appear first would allow us to have the best of both worlds. As stated in my feature request (the first one linked above):

> This would work like the four special tags on meta: all special tags
> are sorted by popularity first, then all normal tags are sorted by
> popularity.

This would allow us to always have the RPG system/edition (where specified) be clearly listed for a question, while also letting us include other relevant tags (even when they're more popular than the system/edition tag) without causing any problems.

In addition, as stated in the second question linked above:

> It doesn't help that a lot of RPGs have names which might just refer
> to a game element or procedure of play: [fate](/questions/tagged/fate) [fiasco](/questions/tagged/fiasco)
> [monster-of-the-week](/questions/tagged/monster-of-the-week) [dungeon-world](/questions/tagged/dungeon-world) [microscope](/questions/tagged/microscope)
> [kingdom](/questions/tagged/kingdom) [follow](/questions/tagged/follow)

Even when a tag like this appears in the tag list, some users (especially new users) don't realize that the tag refers to a particular RPG system; some of them simply assume the question is about D&D, and answer accordingly. This just results in frustration/annoyance for both the querent (who's getting an answer that isn't relevant to them at all) and the other users that help moderate the site (because they then have to flag it as "not an answer" and/or vote to delete it). It also contributes to an overall sentiment (well-documented on our Meta) that RPG.SE often feels more like "D&D.SE", making players of other RPGs feel unwelcome - or at least feel like the site isn't going to be useful to them.

The two suggestions I've linked above - making it so RPG system/edition tags can always appear first in the tag list of a question, and displaying the tag in a special color - would help avoid/solve these recurring problems. This would be a definite quality-of-life improvement for RPG.SE.

(I think there are other sites that could also benefit from the ability to designate certain tags as "special" as well, such as tags for particular video games/franchises on the Arqade, or specific programming languages on Stack Overflow - RPG.SE is just the one I've spent the most time on.)

Comment: Also, a related 2011 feature request from the Arqade Meta: [Make a special tag class for “game tags”.](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1651/56295)

Comment: "*RPG.SE often feels more like "D&D.SE"*" [It really does](https://i.imgur.com/X26w8Yd.png). But that's probably a separate topic.

Comment: @VLAZ: It's come before on our Meta... a few times: [Dungeons and Dragons is dominating the site in terms of page views](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7278/33569), [Only D&D on this Stack?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8642/33569), [I just showed up here. Should I be somewhere else if I play other RPGs more than D&D?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11514/33569) - and also: [How do we get more questions about things besides D&D 4e?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/774/33569)

Comment: This could also be helpful on code golf, for winning criteria.

Comment: I guess that most sites could benefit from special (top level) tag sets that could appear in a different color (or with an icon or whatever) and that should be controllable by the community itself.

Answer (score 27):

#### Archive feature

On Ask Ubuntu we have a lot of questions, and especially a lot of answers, which were super relevant and useful to a lot of people at the time they were posted, but which no longer have value in helping folks find out how to do x, because how to do x has changed over time. Many such posts are highly upvoted, jump up on search engines, and if they are answers show at the top of the by-default-vote-ordered pile.

We don't delete such posts, and I don't think we should delete them or even necessarily edit them to update them (often this would involve replacing all of the content, perhaps making it the same as other existing answers to the same question), because they have a social history value and perhaps can be of use to people interested in user experience and various other aspects of software development - who knows? But the mass of obsolete material is only increasing over time and gradually making it harder for visitors and reviewers to find answers that actually give accurate and current information. It's not at all the case that everything old is out-of-date, but enough of our posts *are* out-of-date that it's an issue.

Recently [Monica](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/madhens) from the Ubuntu community team gave me the idea of an archive feature. The way I think it could work would be different for questions and answers.

For answers, 5 users could vote to archive an answer, and it would be pushed to the bottom of the page in all views under a notice that the below answers are archived and may not work any more.

For questions, 5 users could vote to archive a question, and a notice would appear at the top of it stating that it is archived and may no longer be relevant, and optionally and preferably, linking to newer questions with current answers on the same topic.

Comment: There currently is work being done to adress the problem of outdated answers: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/361097/outdated-answers-project-kicking-off-on-stack-overflow

Comment: @Luuklag do you think I should post this there instead (or as well)? (I totally disagree with Glorfindel's answer there about Ask Ubuntu. That silly close reason we have does nothing to address this)

Comment: If you have something new to bring to the table there (be sure to also check out the linked MSO question) go ahead and post there as well. Do make sure you answer that question specifically, so a blatant copy-paste is not recommended.

Comment: are you aware of [meta-tag:historical-lock] feature available for questions?

Comment: @gnat yes but I don't like that feature because it prevents anyone from ever interacting with the post again, and doesn't actually help people find up-to-date information instead. The main problem we have is with answers rather than questions anyway.

Comment: @Zanna I read the recent *outdated answers* threads and this archive feature seems to rarely have been mentioned. It's an interesting perspective because Ask Ubuntu and SO are different in nature and a particular site probably allows to narrow the overall problem.

Comment: @bad_coder I think Machavity came up with [something somewhat like this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/405368/6192153) on MSO, mediated by tag badges. I like the idea of using tag badges as this requires field-specific knowledge more than other types of review, but there aren't enough tag badge holders on our site for that to be workable unfortunately. Still, I'm sure there's some way to get it done :)

Comment: Ask Ubuntu doesn't have said problem. This is something created by the community. This [question have been updated since '13](https://askubuntu.com/q/333795/169736) every time a new version of Ubuntu comes out. Do that for every question and this problem disappear. Make questions less about the version and more about the problem.

Comment: @Braiam Ask Ubuntu *is* the community. This longstanding problem is not going to go away without better tools. People do write new answers to old questions but the new answers are stuck at the bottom of the page. Some questions have no relevance to new versions (e.g. stuff about unity DE). People close as dupe without checking whether the answers are still current.

Comment: At the very least you can already edit outdated questions and answers and add a notice that the practice is outdated nowadays (maybe with some reasoning why and preferably with a link to a better solution). Not sure if the archive sort at bottom feature is the best solution. A trending sort order (which is on by default) might work better/more smoothly.

Answer (score 25):

**Site-specific new user onboarding**

Onboarding new-users has been a focus of several past [and current](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/07/29/the-loop-our-community-public-platform-roadmap-for-q3-2021/) initiatives. However, from my perspective these have always been too focused on Stack Overflow.

As moderators and curators on other sites, we don't have any ability to change how the asking process looks for our users even when our requirements and the types of "bad" questions we get are completely different from the ones on SO.

New users shouldn't be so surprised that medical advice and self-help questions are off-topic on MedicalSciences.SE, Biology.SE, and Psych&Neuro.SE after they type in their question (and no, the ugly disclaimer on [MedicalSciences](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/) is not the way to go; it's also not even visible on the mobile site. This is a legal/liability feature, it doesn't do anything for site quality and anyone experienced in dodging ads and other irrelevant material on the interwebs is going to automatically filter out that yellow background text as "extra stuff not relevant for me to read"). New users to Academia.SE shouldn't be so surprised that the site isn't for asking about their organic chemistry homework.

Close votes and comments should be about responding to the questions that still sneak by the information, not the sites' first line of defense.

**Do your research, then give us the tools**

I don't think its feasible for the CMs or any other staff to review these sorts of things for every community. The time commitment would be huge across the whole range of sites. However, you have some dedicated experts in each community that are going to be eager to help write copy for this. Let them.

There will no doubt be more opportunity to do A/B testing on SO to determine how to best present the messaging to get (at least some) new users to actually heed the advice given. However, I think the steps taken on SO should be designed with the rest of the network in mind. Think at an early stage about what might be customizable across the network and how to facilitate that, rather than just doing what makes sense for SO and maybe later kind of squeezing in a half-solution for everyone else.

Comment: I think this would be a better fit [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/368049/mse-feedback-post-feedback-on-q3-2021-community-and-public-platform-roadmap) but I might be wrong.

Comment: @EkadhSingh Perhaps; I wrote it before that post existed but got distracted and just got back to finishing it up now.

Comment: At least two other posts here target a similar issue: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/368034/401068 https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/368007/401068 but I stubbornly wanted to make my own take on it, and those other proposals are themselves also focused on specific aspects of site customization of help/onboarding content.

Comment: I think there’s real promise in this concept and it’s one that I intend to ask my team to develop a couple of experiments around.

Comment: @Philippe Occasional tips [like these](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/127704/578924) would also help with on-boarding in general. But such things could be annoying and there definitely should be a way to disable them.

Answer (score 24):

### Allow more syntax highlighting

[HighlightJS](https://highlightjs.org/) ships [a lot of useful languages](https://highlightjs.org/static/demo/), of which SO & other programming sites only use a small fraction of.

Syntax highlighting is very useful for clarity and readability. If someone posts a AppleScript question, the code would be a lot easier to read, and therefore be understood/answered better, if SO had the AppleScript language mode.

I know that this is because of performance, but since most questions only use one language, would it be possible to dynamically load whatever languages the question requires?

This probably would require a quite substantial overhaul, but I believe it's possible.

Comment: I would add that even for supported languages highlighting is not as rich and distinctive as in code editors. At least for Python.

Comment: @EvgenKo423 I think that's mainly because SO has to use light mode, which can't be as distinctive as dark mode, which most people use.

Comment: Well, the code is on the grey background, so I'm not sure...

Answer (score 24):

I don't have any specific community in mind. My request is more generic and about the need of the community as whole.

My request isn't technical, and it isn't about policy, but I guess it fits under "something about the environment in which you operate", so I'll give this a try.

The environment in which I operate is Stack Exchange as whole, and something there is still off. Something still prevents many people from getting back to full activity.

So, my request is for the company to fix a major past mistake which has lasting effect to this day. Many, both inside and outside the company, keep saying it's impossible, and maybe it is; yet I think there's no harm in asking anyway. All it needs is one single apology, done properly.

Those who need to know what I talk about exactly know it already; I prefer not to go into specific details here as it would lead to undesired side effects and my request will be lost in the smoke. The essence of the request is simple: fix a past mistake. You (the company) already made major steps towards this.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  My position on this situation remains the same as it did last week: the situation happened prior to my arrival, and I wasn't there.  I think it would be height of hubris for me to think that I could come through and thread the needle so carefully as to make people on both sides feel okay with things. Instead, I'd rather look forward and do my best to see that a similar situation never comes up again.

Comment: @Philippe totally fair, but still, you're in a position where you can just hand over the needle to someone who can use it, hence I was asking.

Comment: @Philippe that's a cop-out, this isn't a "both sides" situation where two factions within the community were pitted against each other or something. A couple of people within the company just decided to channel their inner pointy-haired boss, kick a veteran volunteer to the curb and, to add insult to injury (it seems) as a final step had a bunch of lawyers put a gag order on her. As pointed out in my answer linked above, there absolutely are things that the company could do to fix this & I will take refusal to even look into it as a signal that nothing meaningful has changed since.

Comment: I rather think that you just proved my point for me. When an attempt to say "anything I say will aggravate somebody, so I'm going to avoid saying anything"... aggravates someone... well, yeah.  It reconfirms to me the fact that there is significant study and work to be done before I would even think about wading in there.  Not to mention, I still have to answer to legal. Ultimately, this is not my decision to make.

Comment: @Philippe well, I read your position so far as not wanting to do that significant study and work in the first place and that *is* a cop-out. Nobody is expecting you to have an instant opinion on the matter, and obviously you bear no personal responsibility for something that happened while you weren't there, but you inherit the problems created by those who occupied your position before you.

Comment: Also it really isn't a situation of "anything I say will make someone mad" like it so often is when there's a highly polarized, intra-community struggle. This wasn't one. Try saying "I'll make a serious effort to look into it and take it up with my superiors even if it might be inconvenient" and it's highly unlikely anybody will be seriously aggravated :)

Comment: I think you're reading things I never said.  :-)  I'm not afraid of study and work - but I do have to prioritize things based on several different stakeholders, timeliness requirements, and many other factors.  But the reality is, even when that is said and done, it's not my call.  I can advocate all day but it's not my call.  But I will compromise:  I will say that I will make a serious effort to look into it and follow up internally (even if inconvenient) at the appropriate time, based on workload and prioritization.

Comment: @Philippe To be honest, not saying the right thing will also poison people against you here. "He knows and did nothing" is significantly worse then "He tried to address it but failed / it was tone deaf". I appreciate this is not your decision to make, and i'm sorry that you're going to continue harvesting the bad feelings for this, but unless it's resolved this will never stop, nor should it. Anyone coming into a leadership position at SE that does not positively address this issue will be seen as complicit in the ongoing harm that is being done still.

Comment: @Pekka - there was totally inter community struggles. Meta was a mess and we closed down the mod chatroom temporarily. It would be inaccurate, even after so much time, or maybe especially so, to believe 'no one would be mad'.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek weren't those struggles largely about the new speech rules though, around pronouns and such, rather than the way Monica specifically was treated for being doubtful about some of those rules (while being more of an actual "trans ally" in real life than most of us here), and the insinuations made about her to media outlets (or at least one outlet) afterwards? I'm not suggesting revisiting the former.

Comment: The new speech rules were... a bit of a distraction, and an unwelcome one - they were both the cause of these events and kinda made things messy -  there's an entire spectrum of how people felt about events, and different viewpoints. I would point out (and some of this leaked) - we had to freeze the Teacher's Lounge a  over auguments related to this issue - and they went on for quite a bit. It is a monumental mess, and every action or inaction is likely to have its advocates and detractors. If someone *can* bring it to closure, and keep *most* folks happy,

Comment: I think it would be an epic work of diplomacy

Comment: @JourneymanGeek true, but rather than "epic work of diplomacy" which might as well be actually impossible, what Pekka asks for is one single apology. Sadly, might be as impossible as amending all mistakes done with the hundreds of moderators. :/

Comment: @Philippe "...I wasn't there..." True, but the company was there. On behalf of the company, anyone from the company could actually do something, if the present company wanted that. Maybe you could just mention it internally sometimes that there is some kind of public demand for action and then together with others the company could decide to either act or not to act. I wouldn't see it as a personal thing, rather as a company thing.

Answer (score 20):

### Better accessibility.

When users with disabilities struggle to use SE, this also means that they may not have much of a voice here.

In the 2021 developer survey, 4,1% respondents claimed to have a physical difference with the majority being blind or having difficulty seeing. This is the highest result when we compare to past surveys which varied between 2,8% and 1,7% of respondents claiming to have a physical difference. We don't have such a survey for the whole of SE as far as I'm aware so this is the most representative number I can find for our user base.

According to a [2017 article from the Pew Research Center](https://www.pewresearch.org/fact-tank/2017/04/07/disabled-americans-are-less-likely-to-use-technology/), "[...] there have also been dozens of lawsuits in recent years, claiming some websites are not accessible to those with disabilities."

This doesn't relate to a specific need of one of our communities but back in 2018, our former SO product manager [Joe Friend](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/306267/249658) wrote :

> I want to see us make improvements for a range of users with differing
> abilities. My perspective is that improvements to users with specific
> needs can lead to improvements for everyone.

**Better accessibility would not only make all of our communities more diverse and welcoming, it would also mean an improved experience for all users.**

There was a lot of discussion around being inclusive on SE in 2019. Back then, a few moderators started compiling a long list of unresolved accessibility issues related to screen readers, color perception, keyboard accessibility, dyslexia, visual impairment, tremor, and more. Unless they've been resolved, [some of these issues seemingly affect core community mechanisms](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/310596/screen-reader-users-cannot-discover-badges-and-reputation).

A long list of unaddressed accessibility issues on MSE can be found by searching with the following queries:

[Questions on MSE including the accessibility and feature-request tags that are not status-completed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion%20%5Baccessibility%5D%20and%20%5Bfeature-request%5D%20-%5Bstatus-completed%5D)

or

[Questions on MSE including the accessibility, bug, and feature-request tags that are not status-completed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion%20%5Baccessibility%5D%20AND%20%5Bbug%5D%20-%5Bstatus-completed%5D)

Comment: One important thing to note is that accessibility solutions  don’t just benefit the people that need them, they are features that can benefit everyone. I have no trouble hearing and I enable subtitles often. Text to speech sure is nice to have when I’m driving and get a text. I turn off images when I browse sometimes to conserve bandwidth and battery life. Accessibility is not about catering to some percentage of an audience that depends on specific features, it’s about making a site/service/video game easier to use and more flexible  for everyone.

Comment: and yet... both of the most notable changes have resulted in a site that is harder to read.

Comment: And better accessibility benefits ***all*** users. Perhaps add something about this to your answer?

Comment: @P.Mort.-forgotClayShirky_q That is why I had added the quote by Joe Friend. I calculated the percentages because I'm curious but they seem to be construed like catering to a small subset of users which is not what I intended at all...

Comment: Sort of related. There is [an episode of the *99% Invisible* podcast](https://99percentinvisible.org/episode/episode-50-deafspace/) that is about architecture accommodating deaf people. I found it quite fascinating. It also does point out how designing for the deaf benefits the hearing people, as well. Some of the design decisions are to limit the eye strain, for example. It is a 12 minute episode, and a great example for how helping people with disabilities can help all.

Answer (score 18):

### [SF & F](https://fantasy.stackexchange.com)

I would like to see a custom question-flow for asking story ID requests. They're about half of our questions, most of them are by new / drive-by users, and most need to be coached in the comments to tell us when they read or watched it, where, what language, and so on.

A custom question-flow that would ask a (new) user to address those points would be really helpful.

Comment: If we're truly waving the magic wand and to generalise further a custom ask editor based on tags that mods could edit and customise.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot or even a manual choice: "do you want to identify a story?", which could be "do you need help with a homework assignment?" or "do you have a piece of non-working code?" on SO.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot that would require tags to come *first*...

Comment: @Pureferret Good point. Tags are now suggested based on the question body, not the other way around.

Comment: Maybe it's time to revive the Ask Question Wizard.

Comment: Custom question flows might be good in guiding users on many parts of SE, but the benefit needs to be balanced with the effort to maintain these custom question flows.

Answer (score 18):

**TeX.StackExchange**: restore previous "community promotion" conventions

Within the TeX/LaTeX community, local user groups have used the community promotion ads to good effect to announce their annual meetings or similar events.  Such events are both time-specific and time-critical, and after an event has occurred, an ad dedicated to that event should be replaced by something more general.

This year, however, proposing this year's ads wasn't even launched until late spring, and the ads won't be activated until August 1.  By then, at least one group's meeting had already taken place, and the annual meeting of the international TeX Users Group (TUG) starts on August 5; not much time for a useful announcement.

Even worse, it will no longer be possible to replace an outdated ad.  This simply leads to embarrassment and the perception, especially by newcomers, that the site is not current, or even that it is not to be trusted.

This is a request to restore the previous practice -- Start proposals for a new year's ads at the beginning of the year, or even a month or two earlier, and activate them as soon as possible after January 1.  And allow replacement of "expired" announcements as appropriate.

It's also the case that "commercial" ads for SE/SO are exhibited much more frequently than the community ads, and I've rarely seen *only* a community ad without it being preceded by one of the organization's ads.  While we recognize that SE/SO needs to support itself, it's sad that this appears to be given much higher priority than the needs of its users.

Comment: Could the mods (ab)use the Upcoming Events bulletin for this? (I'd like a more dynamic ad system than the new one, just wondering for this particular case).

Comment: I will make a note - I'm not sure what drove the timing this year, but I"ll ask.

Answer (score 17):

As I mentioned in chat when suggesting the topic, I'm afraid my "pet peeve" or thing that I would change would be the relatively new policy of having to be [18 or older to become a diamond moderator](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/357380/294691).

As I wrote in my answer(s) to the original announcement, there have been numerous moderators around the network who became moderators under the age of 18, including some of the most well-known or influential moderators on the network.
I also became a moderator at the age of 14. I stepped down before turning 18, which meant this policy change didn't affect my personally - I reclaimed my diamond a few days ago, and I just turned 19 - but it still felt like a slap in the face when it was announced. Given the history of young moderators on the network, and the literal years of time and effort poured into improving the sites and moderating, it gives the impression that all that effort was never really valued.

The possibility of underage moderators was discussed all the way [back in 2012](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126919/294691) (long before I joined the network). There was a pretty heavy consensus that age should be irrelevant for becoming a moderator, since moderators are selected for ability and temperament in any case (leaving aside the practical issue that it's impossible to actual verify age on the internet).

All this, combined with the votes and responses to the announcement, mean that the community has made its opinion fairly clear: The age of a moderator should be irrelevant. Changing this policy back in order to allow any user who meets the age requirements laid out in the ToS (13 most places, 16 in the EU) to become a moderator, even if it means getting parental permission, would show that the community's values are reflected by the company.

Comment: As I recall - that there were no moderators who were 'underaged' at the time was something that was discussed when this rule instituted. It would have been manifestly unfair to de-mod someone for a rule that wasn't in place when they were elected. I think part of the concerns was that we'd been moving to a more formal/'legal' mod agreement and the potential for NDAs for certain activities of the mod council (and the working groups that for most part have replaced it) . Its not a reflection of those mods abilities, rather "we need this, to open up these other things, cause these things changed"

Comment: @JourneymanGeek That's not fully accurate, now I can't be reinstated as a mod on Drones.SE due to the new policy.

Comment: Well if you were removed for being underaged I feel that reinstatement without preconditions when you hit 18 should be a thing even with the new rules.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Considering a site can change a lot in a few years, I could only agree on that if it was a matter of months, a year at most. After that, elections are the way to go. If the site hasn't changed too much *and* the ex-moderator was any good at their job, they should have no problem getting a landslide victory.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek It is as far as I know.

Comment: @Xnero - that's a bit deceptive - your age doesn't relate to why you're not a moderator currently. While it prevents you from being reinstated, there's other issues.

Comment: @Catija The email you sent me in December says otherwise.

Answer (score 17):

## Built-in leaderboards on [Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/)

I'm somewhat active on [Codidact Code Golf](https://codegolf.codidact.com/). I also use the [Graduation Userscript](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7897/graduation-design-ideas/7955#7955) on CGCC (created back before we graduated and had a design). One feature that both of these have that I'd love to be a part of CGCC by default is leaderboards:

[image: leaderboard screenshot]

And a little tooltip that tells you the winner:

[image]

As this is doable with a userscript, it mainly involves a bit of custom HTML + JS being added to our site, so it's not even too crazy of a change. Currently, this is only for challenges with the [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) tag, so that might be a bit of a challenge to do.

---

I find this a super useful feature to have (and is really the only reason I still use an outdated and failing userscript). It allows me to not only see if someone has posted an answer in the language I use quickly (something that can be hard when you have 3 or more pages of answers), but it also gives me a target to beat when golfing.

This is also something that uniquely fits with CGCC. Such a feature makes no sense on any other Q&A site, and would show that SE is willing to put in more effort into site-specific requests.

Comment: I think that this often goes against our stated view on inter language competition.  I think that having leader-boards could possibly hurt our site if not implemented very carefully.

Comment: I would rather have the ability to tag answers by language for easy searching and filtering.

Comment: Answers by language with best score (in ABC order of language names, not the byte count) looks good to me. This kind of "leaderboard" has been implemented using Stack Snippets like on [Hello World](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/55422/78410), but they're hard to track and maintain, and are actually broken now.

Comment: There's also scope for this to cover SFF questions asking for the 'earliest' if we could work people into sticking to a particular format.

Comment: One small potential advantage: This will obviously require some sort of (loose) standardized format for the language name and byte count, which means other automated tools for analyzing things like language golfiness will work better.

Comment: Looking at the broader picture, it feels like this could be done with a feature that allows extra JavaScript to be inserted in the site's footer. Mind you, that is a [feature that already exists for one site](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/a/4430). (Yes, this means the community takes up the slack for development. The "put in more effort into site-specific requests" thing seems like it's not going to happen.)

Answer (score 15):

### Encourage more community members on [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) in curating minor issues in questions in favor of closing them

As an example, I regularly see good or at least acceptable questions asked, but then the asker adds something like

- "do you know any further references for solving the problem"?

at the end. Guess what happens - the question collects close-votes, because questions for third-party resource requests are not allowed (interestingly, answers *giving* references to third-party resources is not only fine, but encouraged).

It gives me the impression certain members don't read the question, but are only interested in scanning them for buzzwords, casting a vote and not even try to give the asker a helpful comment. This is especially frustrating when the close-voters do have enough rep and could easily edit those buzzwords out of the question (or at least leave a comment to give the OP a chance to remove the critical part *before* the question gets closed).

Other cases include questions which are closed because the title does not really match the question (but could be easily fixed when someone takes the time to read and understand what the OP is really asking).

Of course, when I see such cases, I try to fix the issues by myself, but when I count the number of people willing to do so, including the diamond moderators, it seems we are pretty understaffed.

Comment: We've sometimes had similar issues (or perceived issues) on RPG.SE, with users voting to close something as off-topic for asking for RPG/tool/etc. recommendations instead of focusing on the parts of the question that are answerable/allowed on the site. (There have been quite a few conversations on Meta about that sort of potential problem.) Thankfully, the community is generally pretty good about helping users ask "stackable" questions rather than just closing them and walking away.

Comment: Ho ho, same exact thing happens all the time on [Music: Practice and Theory](https://music.stackexchange.com/). Good one.

Comment: Re *"certain members don't read the question, but are only interested in scanning them for buzzwords"*: Yes, that is a well-known problem on most Stack Exchange sites. (That excludes homework/code writing sites like *[Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour)* and *[Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour)*.)

Comment: That's a general issue. If you can salvage a question (for example by removing parts) you should prefer that over simple close voting. But often that's not possible, because essential information really is missing. Editors should not have to guess.

Answer (score 15):

A while ago I suggested a [Dictionary look up in the side-bar](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3125/9161) for [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/). If I had a magic wand, we would have an easy way to find credible definitions for words and idioms without leaving the site so we could start off [on the same page](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/on+the+same+page). There are many dictionaries online, and they vary widely in quality; we discussed that a bit here: [What sorts of dictionaries should we use on ELL?](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4721/9161)

We often ask questions similar to “Did you look up *word* in the dictionary and why didn’t that help?” This isn’t an attempt to try to short circuit questions before they’re asked, but to help us get past the language barrier and try to understand why they’re confused.

Comment: I think some other sites could benefit utilising such a sidebar for image lookup. If memory serves, a while ago Anime.SE even had an extensive (and I think quite painful) cleanup of questions that could be answered by a simple image lookup

Answer (score 15):

#### Force new users to take a quiz

Yes, this is fairly radical. But many sites get so many off-topic questions that it's taking the most time of all the moderation tasks. Much of that can be prevented, since many people simply didn't know their question would be ill-received.

All users that are new to the site (1 rep, ignore association bonus) or recently had a question closed get a small quiz. An open-book quiz that's so ludicrously easy that the only way to fail it is if you haven't read the rules. Failing the quiz locks you out for a minute, after that you can try again. 3 questions at most. Heck, we can start with 1, that should already do a bit.

We can't force-feed the rules into new users, but even with the new fancy modals not everyone reads what we shove in their faces. When the questions get closed, some users get really aggressive about it.

Code Review has a couple of rules. 6 of them are very easy and explained in [the help center](//codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

- Is code included directly in my question?
- Am I an author or maintainer of the code?
- Is it actual code from a project rather than pseudo-code or hypothetical code?
- To the best of my knowledge, does the code work as intended?
- Do I want the code to be good code?
- Do I want feedback about any or all facets of the code?

If everyone that posted would honestly answer all those with 'yes', we'd lose about 90% of all off-topic questions. This would save a lot of fresh users the frustration of getting their questions closed and make the review queues a lot less populated, which greatly helps with the improved-reviewing-experience SE's got going on for a while now.

I'd like a checklist to have people check all 6 of those, but I know that's asking too much. So I'll settle for quizzing a few of those points at random.

Comment: Or complete the (hypothetical) Stack Exchange Onboarding Game™.

Comment: @P.Mort.-forgotClayShirky_q not sure if you're saying this in jest but IMO, we *can* have something like this. This can be tied to the gamification. system - you can have a short trivia-like game with questions like: "When is it appropriate to edit: a) when I want to say thanks b) when I notice a problem with the post". At the end, if the user got a good score that gets them some rep. And maybe badges This can be repeated to, say, 100 rep or so. Similar to how suggested edits give *some* rep but with a cap.

Comment: There's something to this idea; the more I think about it the more it intrigues me.  If we could incentivize them somehow to take a quiz, by giving them something they want, we might get away with it.

Answer (score 14):

### What does your community need?

### MSE:  Fewer off-topic questions from new users.

If I had the magic wand, I would wave it in order to instill a deep, irresistible desire for people new to a community to *go and read the essentials*, first thing.

I've [said it before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/367463/new-community-vp-seeks-your-input-what-should-we-be-looking-to-change-and-what/367806#comment1225592_367806):  I've seen a hell of a lot of off-topic questions on MSE and SO - across the network, actually - from new users that have disregarded the [on-topic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page or the [help center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help) entirely (detailed answers to any questions you might have!).  After being downvoted and deleted, the authors go and post complaints or questions such as [Is it necessary to read all the rules on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/407725/is-it-necessary-to-read-all-the-rules-in-stack-overflow) (rene's [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/407728/13138080) is *on the money* there).

One of the things I would do to help with this: put a popup on the [ask](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) page (just for the newbies) that quotes a few lines from the "Don't ask" page, particularly the bit mentioning:

> To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed, avoid asking ...

Which I personally would change to:

> To prevent your question from being flagged, downvoted and possibly closed or removed entirely...

As that's mostly what I see them complaining about: being downvoted.  If we warn them a bit more strongly, they might listen.

These are just a few ideas.  I might need to formulate a whole new question, but there you are.

Comment: Doesn't the [new ask page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/344513/346823) do this?

Comment: @LShaver No.  It's nice, but the popup already in place lists the basic steps to asking a good question, but not the consequences involved (downvoting, closing) when you don't bother to read the on/off-topic pages.  And that's what they're complaining about.  Telling them what happens to bad questions *before* they post them, right up front, might stem the flow.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/306329/people-get-lost-and-crash-into-meta-maybe-we-need-roadblocks-for-their-safety related tho MSE specific

Answer (score 14):

There is a highly upvoted feature request about this: *[Allow non-bumping minor edits, but review them on /review](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/122567)*.

In some instances (major retaggings, updating dead links, and correcting typos) it might be preferable that the edited posts do not clutter the front page. (To mention an example I saw recently, a community on some site might decide to split some tag into two separate tags - and the only way to deal with the existing questions is to retag them manually.<sup>1</sup>) Of course, it is important that somebody looks at the edits - but that could be resolved by a review queue for minor edits.

This was brought up on several metas. Among them, [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/tour) users seem to be one community that is rather opposed to bumping - in fact, such feature request was brought up by one of the moderators on that site. (Of course, that is just my personal impression - it is possible that there are some other communities which were quite vocal about this feature and I simply did not notice them.)

Here are some examples of posts from per-site-metas related to this issue:

- MathOverflow Meta: [Minor edits, subject to review](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/192) (One of the moderators mentioned in the comments that he communicated about this also with the Stack Exchange team, but there were no updates since then.)
- Mathematics Meta: [Is there a way to edit without bumping the question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29638) (And other similar feature requests: [“Minor edit” feature for trusted users](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/23159) and [Would you like to have the option to edit a question without it being bumped to the main page?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/22171))
- Physics Meta: [Minor edits should not make questions 'active'](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4702)
- Tex-LaTeX Meta: [Minor edit checkbox?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1839) and [Can I edit a post without bumping it to the front page?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6218)

---

<sup>1</sup> A recent example of such action can be seen on Politics: [Better defining the [polling] and [public-opinion] tags](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5879). On a site where I am the most active, I remember [splitting (algebra) into (algebra-precalculus) and (abstract-algebra)](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/473/the-use-of-the-algebra-tag/). The tag (algebra) was [removed from 1500 questions](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1038474/questions-which-no-longer-have-the-given-tag-including-the-editor?tagName=algebra).

Comment: This feature request has consistently been rejected by the main meta crowd for the past 12 years. The canonical may be *[Allow non-bumping minor edits, but review them on /review](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122567/)* (see also [the "Linked" questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/122567) for that). [A 2009 feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26483/).

Comment: @P.Mort.-forgotClayShirky_q I wouldn't call a +100 crowd rejected in this particular case...

Answer (score 12):

Okay, here's a little pet peeve of mine for the wand sprites to look at:

### Tag Reform!

I'm a [Music: Practice and Theory](https://music.stackexchange.com/) native, and recently I've been trying to go through the site's numerous neglected tags and fix them up. I do notice symptoms of a lot of the functionality of tags going completely over the head of most users. In particular:

- **Tag synonyms are over-restricted.** Currently, the requirement to be able to vote on proposed tag synonyms is a net score in that tag of 5, and to suggest tag synonyms one must additionally have the 2500 reputation required to unlock that privilege. Maybe on bigger sites this isn't as much of an issue, but on my home site, I've got the necessary 2.5k rep to suggest synonyms. The trouble is, the smaller less-used tags are the ones that often need synonyms, and it's not easy to get 5 total score in rare tags like [schenkerian-analysis](/questions/tagged/schenkerian-analysis) or [balalaika](/questions/tagged/balalaika), which only have 4 and 3 questions respectively on all of M:P&T! I think *by the time a user amasses 2.5k on a site, they should know enough to be able to at least SUGGEST synonyms*, especially when they're voted upon anyway. In the meanwhile, our site has had just two synonyms [created this year](https://music.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms), and I'm pretty sure that's not a sign of our collective tagging genius.
- **Tag synonyms go relatively unused** (partially because they're so restricted)**.** At this point, they're almost a hidden feature, only accessed by those in-the-know. When was the last time YOU checked your site's Pending Approval section for tag synonyms? The description for the [tag synonym privilege](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms) does provide the necessary information to use the system, but I think we'd see more users start to use this feature if the *pending suggestions could have their own review queue!*
- **Tag wikis are decrepit.** Some of the largest, most common tags have wikis so incomplete that they wouldn't even be valid as answers! They also rarely contain any links to posts or other sources of information. I think it's great that it takes a [trusted user](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/trusted-user) (20k) to directly edit without suggesting, but I believe that with a more visible way to access the tag wiki *(perhaps with a link in the pop-up when hovering over the tag itself, or allowing them to turn up in search results!)*, SE's tags would be more complete and useful for new users. On the plus side, tag wiki excerpts are working just fine across all SE, and I like how they are so accessible (cough cough).
- **Tag wiki excerpts could use a rename.** It can be confusing for new users to learn that tag wikis and tag wiki excerpts are entirely different things - I remember that when I was new, I thought the wiki excerpts WERE the wiki entries (and since it's so hard to find the wiki, how could I have known the difference?). *Why not call them "tag excerpts" instead?*

---

I realize that while this is all my own experience on my specific SE site, I suspect these problems exist on other sites as well, particularly for the smaller ones. I don't know how many of these could be realistically implemented, but I at least feel good about getting these off of my chest.

Here are some more questions to look at about how the tag synonym isn't quite working well enough:

- [Does the tag synonym suggestion system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127459/does-the-tag-synonym-suggestion-system-work)
- [Can we allow 7.5K users to suggest tag synonyms without a score of 5 in the tag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103211/can-we-allow-7-5k-users-to-suggest-tag-synonyms-without-a-score-of-5-in-the-tag)

Even Meta's [What is a Tag Wiki? How do I write one?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214338/401908) answer says about the nonutility of tag wikis, *"Start with the excerpt. That's the part of the tag wiki that users will see first, and the only part that most users will see at all"*.

Oh, and this question was where I got the searchable-tag-wiki idea from: [Improving the tag wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65021/improving-the-tag-wiki)

Comment: Here's a little (hopefully!) temporary workaround that we got running on my alma mater stack: https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3763/37992

Answer (score 10):

## A community advocate.

All communities, large and small, booming and busting, or otherwise moving around in circles all have their own pulse and their own quirks to how they work and how they run.

They also have their own challenges, trials, tribulations and triumphs.

What the communities I'm a part of seem to acutely *lack* is someone advocating for them on a daily basis.

And I don't mean the typical, "I'll run this back and let you know" kind of person.  You could get any ol' intern to do *that* much.  For the record, I've ***never*** found any value in those kinds of roles, either, since it usually means that the community gets to roll on its back and expose its soft, soft belly, and lay prone to the mercy of the company when the person finally gets back to them.  Also by the point we hear back from them, it's a "well we talked about it and this is The Direction™ we're going to be moving in"-kind of deal.

I cannot emphasize this enough.

**No thanks to *that*.**

What I really want is someone who's dedicated themselves to that specific community for years; someone who knows the community, its ins and outs, its quirks and peculiarities, and knows how to read the room.  Someone who the community can rely on and trust to get their voice heard and stand up for them when the company wants to push changes that may impact or disrupt their flow.  Someone who can actually speak to why things are the way they are and break it down so that even D-level or C-level members can understand why.

Someone who isn't going to have panic attacks about talking with us.  Someone who is willing to listen with an open mind and is committed to being transparent.  Someone who actively *cares* about the problems we have and wants to see to it that our problems are solved.  **Someone we can put our trust into** because they would have already built that rapport with us.

Comment: In theory that should be the CMs - least on the company's end, unless you mean a specific 'new' role. Even then - that's a lot of communities with different needs, and even on our end, there's very few folks with super wide knowledge and contacts to be able to do that imo.

Comment: We already have advocates. It's the people willing to speak up *when given the chance to*. Reducing that... "role" down to single person would result in one person that only represents a minority rather than the broad range of people who participate.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek:  In theory, yes.  In practice, no.

Comment: I’m not sure I understand why this role isn’t handled by the mod team. Maybe it could be a more formal aspect of what they do, but who better to represent a community’s interests  than someone elected by it?

Comment: @KevinB:  The point I'm making is that we - as in the community - can only speak so loud about certain issues.  The real problem is that we are often ignored or sidelined in the conversations when Big Decisions are made that have a direct impact to a community, or they're made as proclamations from above.  Yes, we can shout about that as much as we like.  Does that mean we're being advocated for?  Nope!

Comment: @ColleenV:  I really don't think of the diamond mods as advocates of the community to the company.  I think they're out there representing us and our best interests, but I don't have the impression that they talk to the company at the detailed level that I want.  You see, they can say a lot of things and point to a lot of things, and the person that they're saying this to or pointing this out to isn't in context or has to absorb all of this and then run it back.  Remember what I said about "running it back"?

Comment: Mods aren't elected for their ability to represent us.

Comment: @Makoto It might make sense to have the community specifically choose an advocate, because a lot of mods don’t take advantage of the channels mods have to advocate for their community. There is a “team” and a chat room where mods can talk directly to staff and to each other, and the mods who participate there do impact policy in a lot of instances.

Comment: @ColleenV:  I'd really rather it be an organic hiring process.  Someone that the company identifies and recognizes as someone who is capable of helping and leading the community, and is willing to work for the company as well.  It's happened before; no reason why it couldn't happen again - or at least more often.

Comment: Well, you’ll never know the answer if you don’t ask. I find it doubtful the company would hire advocates for each site on top of the CM team. It seems unlikely there would be enough work to keep them busy or that they would provide enough value to the company as a single site advocate. Personally, I wouldn’t want my advocate being paid by the company. It seems like that would put their interests more in line with the company than the site.

Comment: @ColleenV:  There are limits to the commitments of volunteer work that eventually demand compensation for spent time.  I wouldn't see an issue with an advocate being paid by the company so long as it was explicitly clear that was their job role.  Employers can set up parameters for job descriptions and if the role was explicitly only about being an advocate, it really wouldn't matter if they were paid by them.

Comment: And what exactly would they do all day? Not trying to be snarky, just trying to understand.

Comment: One way I could see this being a thing: advocates are a couple of users elected by the sites to represent them (potentially only graduated sites?) similar to mods. These advocates then become more closely integrated with the CM side of SE wrt. communication. How this integration happens is a different matter, I can think of a variety of ways with varying effectiveness/feasibility. One key thing would be that advocates actually have a voice and influence in the company, rather than the current system of "sending in requests" (cont.)

Comment: (cont) I personally don't think it's feasible to actually hire advocates for every community - that's a massive increase in employees, and some sites arguably don't need advocates. Something that could work would be similar to external contractors, where they aren't directly hired for SE, but are a part of the company and its workforce (and it wouldn't be a "primary" job, more something "done on the side")

Comment: @ColleenV:  In essence, their job would be to monitor and watch the Meta discussions and keep abreast of what's happening in the community.  Each community does post discussions and talk about their own various issues there, and it'd be useful for someone to be in-context to what actually goes on or what challenges the communities are facing.  Each community has their own set of challenges to address, and each advocate would need soak-in time to actually understand what it means.

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing:  No elections.  Don't turn this into a popularity contest.  Hiring someone who is committed to the community is better than popular vote.  Have you noticed how many people you've probably never heard of turn up at Moderator election time and try to make a case for how they'll be an awesome mod?  I'd really want to avoid that with this.

Comment: It just doesn’t seem like a full time job to me. Some sites go days without a post on their meta site. Some sites have no issues with the company they need advocates for. I agree that we could use a better way of communicating concerns to the company and getting feedback that we were heard and understood. I’m just not sure that a paid advocate is what we need. I’m an American though, so I probably have a cultural bias against that solution. I’m more inclined toward “the voice of the people” type stuff.

Comment: @ColleenV:  I'm an American as well.  Two other things:  1)  This is a magic wand; don't ruin the magic!  2)  I've seen the progress we've made with insufficient coverage or insufficient advocation or unpaid advocation.  It creates this mess where the a relatively small community which wants or needs support from the overall company has to be extremely patient while the larger communities get activity.  Even in the larger communities, there's always the sense of activity but not for their ultimate benefit.

Comment: I don’t mean to be a pest. Like I said, if you don’t ask, you’ll never know the answer. I am just bad at resisting any opportunity to tell people my opinion ;)

Comment: @ColleenV In a sense - it can be.  If you went out to all, I donno, 180? Communities, I'm sure that a significant part of them would be happy to have someone listen and having a person you know can reach out to and will pass on the message to the right folks. While that was roughly a aspiration of the mod council, balancing another job and that sorta thing is pretty hard. I just see that as a core part of CMing as it should be.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Sure, but the ask here is for someone steeped in the community to advocate for them, not a "pass along the message" liaison. That was my main objection to the mod council. As capable and upstanding as all of those mods chosen by other mods are, I don't have any confidence they truly understand the needs of ELL. Someone can't effectively advocate for ELL and all of the 180 other sites, even if they could advocate at a more general level for the community.

Comment: Without magic (and yes, we're assuming that in our 'wants') I can't see how that would work -- for the large sites, there might be enough work to justify a dedicated advocate But for the minnows? I suspect most minnow mods include it in their activities -- although the plethora of channels doesn't help. 'My' site doesn't need daily advocacy -- in fact it would be a PITA. We have 4 pro-tem moderators, 2 of whom are moderators on other sites -- we're pretty good at advocating for ourselves. I agree with Colleen V. -- it ought to be a formal part of the mod role.

Comment: @ColeValleyGirl:  You gravely understate the scope of this request.  Mods in my understanding are still go-betweens with the company and the community.  This is a radical shift in thinking in that we would actually want someone who's full time job it is to be a part of a community to understand and advocate exactly for what's needed.  Diamond mods aren't in the position to advocate to the company on our behalf since they're cut off from a lot of those kinds of internal conversations that *could* or *do* have an impact on communities until the company is *just about* ready to roll a change out.

Comment: @Mokoto, 'My' community wouldn't know what to do with a full time advocate, except sit them down in the corner and feed them biscuits :)  We don't need a daily advocate -- most changes pass us by un-noticed. For large sites, I can see the value if mods don't have the time or access but in my experience the larger sites get heard anyway. Moreover, I cant see SO recruiting 180+ advocates, many of whom would spend their time twiddling their thumbs -- I'd rather see the money spent on growing the  CM team. A part time advocate might be possible, but many of our smaller communities defy grouping.

Comment: I dunno @ColeValleyGirl, I feel like a community who's been in "Beta" for the longest period of time would have plenty to talk about to an advocate.  At least figuring out a way to get over the hump would be something.  There's also some unique challenges that beta-driven sites face on a constant basis, since...well...if the site never *escapes* beta, what happens next?  How does this community then begin to thrive?  Only our community could heartily speak to that.  But...you probably know this better than I do.  Maybe you don't need an advocate.  But I wouldn't pass one up, personally.

Comment: @Mokoto I wouldn't pass one up if they appeared (and didn't divert funds from somewhere that would be useful). Yet I can't see what they'd actually do for us day-to-day.  Our mods have advocated for leaving beta everywhere it's possible and are waiting for the results of the Q3 lifecycle review. I'm not sure what a hired advocate would add above those of us who have walked the walk since 2012. And as I've posted elsewhere graduating might be a poisoned chalice if the graduated rep limits were applied to us.  Escaping Beta IMO is not an life-and-death issue as long as we're not closed down.

Comment: I'll also challenge the assumption that beta sites don't thrive. We have a lot of hit and run posters, but moving out of beta won't change that -- what we need is changes to the basic SE engine that make it easier to convert hit-and-run posters into people who value sticking around.

Comment: @ColeValleyGirl: That *sounds* like something you need someone to advocate for on your behalf since on the outside I don't know what that would even begin to look like, but someone that's closer to your community could very eloquently speak to.  Also too yes, the graduate from Beta sudden rep limit jump is what did some pretty nasty damage to the moderation of Anime and Manga, as not that many of us are able to even moderate stuff effectively without copious diamond moderator support. So someone to advocate on our side about how these things can impact communities is still a plus.

Comment: @Makoto My basic sticking point is the likelihood of finding somebody who would *really* be able to effectively advocate for use for us and some other communities (which I suspect would end up randomly chosen). Especially since, if we graduated, what would they do then?

Comment: @Makoto, it (stickiness') is also something that would be desirable for a large number (even all) of the smaller sites -- it isn't site specific. And even the larger sites could probably benefif from mor epeople who stay around after their first question.

Answer (score 10):

**[Graphic Design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/)**

Site *Graphic Design* is a bit special in that, at least in theory, everybody on the site should be able to generate their own images. And nearly every question and answer should have an image. The community would want for more people who work as graphic designers to participate and share.

But graphic designers on the whole live by the copyright of their images. So in many instances one can not post the image one needs since that would mean release the copyright for [CC-BY-SA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creative_Commons_license#Seven_regularly_used_licenses). It would be nice if there would be a possibility to modify the copyright release clause a bit for this site so that a stronger community could be built.

But this might be totally out of the question. So at least remind new users of the copyright release when posting images. Similar problems may be on more media focused sites.

*Secondly*: *Graphic Design* would need a mechanism for sharing SVG files.

**PS**: I would like to note that you can not uphold same rules as you use in programming related forums. Since graphic design is about whole visual field at once, highly context sensitive, subjective and has no one right answer. This makes it impractical at times to break into a question without showing what you are doing. Primary teaching mechanism in graphic design is critique which is entirely reliant on showing your work. In the end we can not quantify or feelings into rules, at least not today.

Comment: IANAL, but if you decide to only share a link to your image, SE doesn't own the rights to that image right? It is less then ideal, but should work.

Comment: @Luuklag yes but then you will find people will not see your picture as they are not likely to jump to a offsite link. But more it makes the site poorer becase now pictures are hosted elsewhere. Pictures now A) Can link rot. B) The site looks less inviting to a graphic designer who wants to see pictures not just chase links. C) reduces the information content of the answers and questions. D) Some overeager user may edit the link picture into the post. Which is arguably worse since now they and thus stackexhange violated copyright.

Comment: The way this answer is written has an inherent misconception about copyright. In *no case* does posting on Stack Exchange assign the copyright of any user supplied content. What posting on Stack Exchange does is release the content under a CC BY-SA license (currently CC BY-SA 4.0 for newly contributed content). While that may be what you were intending to communicate, and the difference may not matter for the concern which people have, but it is *substantially* different from a legal perspective vs. assigning the copyright.

Comment: @Makyen ok corrected. In anycase the image now can be shared to any other site which reduces the images potential resale value. And in some cases makes selling the vork near impossible (for example logos). In anycase I dont mind but a lot of users do.

Comment: This is an awesome proposal, thanks a lot. I notice my own participation in GD.SE has plummeted ever since I started paying attention to how SE simply tosses everything into copyleft willy-nilly.

Comment: The difficulty with this is the data dump. Any license that would fix the issue you have with CC-BY-SA would mean that those images wouldn't be able to be in the dump. That would substantially reduce the value of the dump, which might be contriversial with the current trust issues.

Comment: Thats not a problem @user1937198 people who post images on the stack mean them to be posted. The licesnse could be written in a form that means that the picture can only be used as part of the article. So that it cant be separeted for other uses.

Comment: How do you do that whilst allowing people to use the data dump, in a form with similar levels of editing that the SE platform provides? The edit capability allows significantly rewriting an article, and we want to be able to keep that in the knowledge base even if the company goes under.

Comment: SO has been working with this problem for nearly a decade now, and the answer has always been, use an MCVE (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that it is representative of a general problem, not a specific one.

Comment: @user1937198 I would advice you to not try to bring in engineering logic into this. Part of the reason that we can not build a better community is exactly this. Graphic design is not, or atleast graphic designers are not, a purely technical field. Graphic designers are artits first, humanists second. Many in the community on purpose do not want to be overly technical. So how would you take a picture, say Mona Lisa, and talk about feelings. How would you make a minimal reproducible example. Or how would you critique someones picture if you need to make s minimally reproducive version.

Comment: You have to work with the logic of the community you want to build. Not the logic of a different community. In anycase graphic designers to some extent sell unique style combined with solutions to problems. Its perfectly reasonable for them to protect their form language and control their own artistic output.

Comment: @user1937198 I can assure you this is a real problem on GD.SE. Design deals with systems. If the asker only shows a little piece of a work because they don't want to put the whole work in copy-left, we can't really answer properly. So we mostly end up with questions about software tutorials and font/style identification which make it difficult to retain actual graphic designers.

Comment: Also I am not a lawyer i dont know how copyright works in the US. Because copyright works slightly differently in my locale anyway.

Comment: SO's solution was to make design and systems questions off-topic, but thats not a great answer. I suppose this comes back to the knowledge repository principle. If questions need that much context, how are they generalisable? Or does having non-generalisable questions work for now because of the size of the community?

Comment: @user1937198 Graphic design is not a science. There is no one answer to most of the questions. There are different methods and different approaches. Generally nobody dies from graphic design answers. But times change also so the answer that was ok today may not be tomorrow (comic sans once hated is again gaining acceptance). So all of the questions are a bit specialized. It takes skill to see that situation a is same as situation b. Often you have a dupe where you need to explain why its a dupe, which is a separate answer.

Comment: A lot of questions have the banal answer "you draw it", but the asker needs a push on how to do it, where to begin and how to see the thing.

Comment: @user1937198 See [this question and comments](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/145168/logo-design-suggestions-for-how-to-apply-proportions-of-logomark-and-logotype-i) as an example. Even something as "simple" as a logo is a bit of a system or interrelated parts.

Comment: "But this might be totally out of the question. ..." Why? Just insert a HTML img tag and refer to your externally hosted image. That way the copyright is fully retained while the image is shown in the post at the same time. Or does that not work?

Comment: @Trilarion stackexchange hosts images at imgur so that they have some insurances that the link will not be lost. If you point to external resource like my own webhost it can dissapear at any time. Many of the posts will probably outlive the person who wrote the answer.

Comment: @joojaa If you want to retain full copyright on your work but also show it on a StackExchange, there will always be a certain risk that copyrighted content is pulled (just revoking the permission to use it here for example). It's not only imgur that is an insurance, it's also the content license. External links are the only way around that, but they also must be by definition non-essential to the question, i.e. the question must stand on its own without it. That's hard. Maybe it's the equivalent of question having to be helpful also for others not only for yourself.

Comment: @Trilarion Yeah thats what I'm trying to tell you. A) images on graphic design are almost always essential. Because imagery *is the topic*. - Means linking to same source as rest of stackexhange and no image no graphic design subexhange B) Releasing copyright, separate form the article is problematic since graphic designers deal in selling images thus they can not ask about images. Being separately licensed from text like its is now is not ok. C) It is very hard to make a minimal working example in more than half of the cases. No images on GD is like no functional code on stackexhange.

Comment: @joojaa One could create mockups, i.e. the minimal possible generic image that still reveals the problem to be asked about without giving away too much original content. It would mean that the solutions may not be that specifically applicable and some additional effort, but at least it would be a viable way forward without changing any license or rules.

Comment: @Trilarion sometimes but not often. We discussed this allready in the comment thread. The problem is that graphic design is not code. But rather being evaluated by a human brain. The brain sees the whole thing you can not turn it off or partially turn it off. Most of the time the question is that something is off, you cant evaluate this without the context. Even when you do a mockup you realize layer that it does not show your error. Simply you can not ask about a problem with a logo without showing the logo, which again is no no since you can now nolonger sell a exclusive right to the logo.

Comment: But more importantly automatically having copyright and shielding copyright is a part of the culture of graphic design. We simply can not attract the crowd we want with current rules. We want to be *graphic design* stackexhange, not silly graphics questions for technical people. Which is what we keep becoming not that those questions are unwelcome just that irs not conductive for our main goal. So @Trilarion dont try to rationalize a holistic humanist art from the point of view of technology and hard science. It does not work. Ive tried, it dont work.

Comment: @joojaa I readily believe you that you have much more experience than me in the subject and that you have tried a lot already, but the whole content license of SE also has proven itself quite useful, maybe not in your case. If you really aren't able to create a meaningful mockup for your actual problem, it might be so specific that a solution to it would only help you and maybe nobody else. This is also a bit against the spirit of the StackExchanges that want to create knowledge bases that help more than a single person each time.

Comment: @joojaa  I'm not 100% convinced that mockups do not work even for logos and with a different than the desired context but if you say so then yes, that would need a different license. As a workaround I would go back to what I said initially, just link to and display any external content and relax the rules about questions having to be complete without external content. Trying to preserve content that is copyrighted won't work anyway, I guess.

Comment: Maybe it could be clarified a bit how the content license would need to be changed exactly. Something like "All rights reserved. Limited usage right to show on URL XXX within the context of a SE Q&A."? Or something different. Is there a similar established license already available that would achieve that?

Answer (score 9):

### Provide more details about spoiler content without revealing

Similar to how code fences can provide a language, I would like spoilers to be specifiable by certain words or correspond to tags on a question.

I mainly want this on *[Science Fiction & Fantasy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour)* (SFF) to encourage people to use them more, knowing they can have TV shows, movies and books they've read 'white listed' so the spoiler is show by default. This could be applicable on *[Movies & TV](https://movies.stackexchange.com/tour)*, *[Literature](https://literature.stackexchange.com/tour)* and even maybe *[Puzzling](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour)* (perhaps more sites?)

But whilst discussing this, it seemed like it would also be worth using this to let people hide distressing images/text content necessary for the question or answer and perhaps having [content warning/trigger warning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trauma_trigger#Trigger_warnings) (CW/TW) lists in network profiles that blocked you from seeing it unless you 'consent'. That could be applicable on so many more sites, like [Interpersonal Skills](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/tour) (IPS), [Parenting](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/tour), [Politics](https://politics.stackexchange.com/tour), and the list goes on.

I imagine it could look like this:

`>!{star wars, shooting} Han shot first`

and render like this:

[image: Standard spoiler image, with the phrase "Warning content contains star wars and shooting content.]

Comment: I agree with the overall idea, though I think that mockup leaves something to be desired in terms of aesthetics... :P

Comment: @v2blast it leaves a **lot** to be desired. :-p

Comment: @V2Blast [Sometimes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/342791/278659), a crappy mockup actually gets used in the final product :-)

Answer (score 8):

Eleven years later: "[Invite low rep user to a chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/59716/6309)"

I would like to switch comments to chat, even if the OP has not enough rep to join a chat room (meaning [less than 20](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/chat)).

That was [studied in 2011](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/90972/6309), for instance to [allow temporary guest accounts in chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/82738/6309).

This should not be abused, as it could transform a Q&A site into a giant chat space.
I propose to limit that privilege to user with a certain reputation level.
Say... [1 Million rep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dr._Evil).
(Or, as [proposed in 2015](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/252690/6309), 30K: on level up the [current highest privilege with 25K](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges))

Answer (score 8):

#### Retain existing users

This is important for small sites on which each user who decides to leave, is a noticeable loss for the whole community.

In the past years, SO put a lot of effort into attracting new users. That's nice! However on specialized sites, where there might not be a never ending supply of new users, it might be worthwhile to also search for ways to retain the existing users.

Just one example of something your team could look into: on tex.se I've witnessed several users leave due to conflicts with other users. Maybe SO could try to provide tooling to avoid or stop conflicts before they escalate? At the moment it seems the only option is waiting until a conflicts is heated so much that mods step in with suspensions, but maybe things like [Add the ability to ignore users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3353/add-the-ability-to-ignore-users) could avoid some of these conflicts in the first place?

(This is just one example I could think of, don't focus too much on this particular example. I'm sure you have people with much better qualified to identify possibilities to improve user retention)

Comment: Mods have plenty of non-suspension options, including public and private talks with the users in question.

Comment: What kind of conflict?

Comment: @P.Mort.-forgotClayShirky_q All kinds. One of the most active users left after a conflict with another users about missing attribution for code. There were cases in which a user mass downvoted a user giving reasons like "did not like the code indention" (no, this is not python, code indention does not influence functionality), or - from my personal experience - a user who would not stop to invalidate other users work of flagging low quality posts and doing reviews by kicking out posts from the queue by doing unnecessary edits.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz - thanks for this. I agree that ideally we could build some things into the interface for this.  As a first step, I've been thinking about expanding the mod trainings that we offer to include things like conflict deescalation in an online context.

Comment: Part of the issue here is that the comment system is broken and  there is no way for users to get rid of discussions they don’t want under their posts and stop every comment from pinging them without moderator intervention. It takes two to tango, so separating discussion from posts doesn’t entirely solve the problem, but allowing users to turn off notifications for a post would be a step that might help.

Answer (score 7):

## Time Travel! (Or at least a cautionary tale of community dynamics)

There's a handful of early communities that kinda fell apart, and quite a lot of missteps with good intentions and poor execution that hurt communities as a whole.

But we can't roll back the past so I think I'd bring up my former second community, before this one, as a cautionary tale. I think its *vitally* important not to assign blame, I'm in a fairly unique situation where I've kinda heard at least two sides of the story (and have something approaching the truth). I'm sure there's other versions of this story, and I do hope folks correct me where there's a mistake.

I used to be very active on Server Fault back in the day. My job -3 let me work on servers (and $deity, I miss that), and they had an active, if a little rowdy community.

There's not 'one' factor that led the core of the community to leave - but one of them was a disagreement over scope (If memory serves - over hosting panels), and one of the mods automating closing them (He was a bit overenthusiastic). I'm of the opinion Shog did what was best in the situation ([Relevant meta post here - and the broader thread might be useful reading of history for y'all](https://meta.serverfault.com/a/8058/33193), and Hopeless did what he felt was best, but the end result was massive drama. There's a few additional parts of the story - that aren't public (I am under the impression talking to *other* folks that the mod in question was kinda tied up in work - which lead to an extra break down in communication). In short, it was a bit of 'cascading things going wrong all at once'.

This *probably* was compounded by ongoing issues (cause $deity - I seem to recall a fairly painful cultural shift at the time, not all bad) and a bit of a tug of war over scope.

So much of the drama and tension between the community and company are a result not of malice but of communication break downs. I suspect its vitally important, especially as the community team ramps up to not just consider the *problem* at hand but the people involved, the knock on effects that a particular action has, and the awareness that sometimes solving a problem causes other problems. There's other examples of this of course, but this feels like a good place to consider.

This isn't impossible, just... probably incredibly hard. It needs both mods to know who to talk to (and who they are talking to), and a fairly deep knowledge of the community that needs help and guidance.

Comment: What do we want?   "TIME TRAVEL!"  When do we want it?   "DOESN'T MATTER!"

Comment: Quite a lot of what I do is in the awareness that I am travelling forward in time, to my inevitable demise :D.

Comment: @Criggie "NOW!" What do we want? "TIME TRAVEL!" When do we want it?

Comment: @Criggie, you now owe me a new keyboard.

Answer (score 7):

### Automatic accepting

Code Golf has [made noise before](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8363/66833) about removing/modifying the way accepting works on the site, as it counteracts our idea that code golf challenges are competitions within languages (so Python competes with other Python answers, not with Perl), and leaves the awarding of the winning answer (for non-code golf challenges) up to the challenge asker. Due to site culture, this mostly results in the winner being awarded the checkmark, but this sometimes fails, often due to newer users. Additionally, we also have a principle that, at the bare minimum, every challenge *must* have an [objective scoring criteria](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8130/66833).

This means that automatic accepting of the winning answer would, in theory, be entirely possible. Practically speaking, this isn't doable unless you had a magic wand, as the complexities of a system *actually* determining the winner from some of the weirder criteria we've had, such as [the sum of the scores (as defined by a formula) of all your answers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/49223/66833). However, by making accepting an answer a fully automated process, CGCC would be able to more effectively use accepting as a way of marking and rewarding the winning answer.

Comment: If you could write some sort of query that parses the winning answer from a series of headers, that would save a lot of work.

Comment: Have you (that is, the community) developed some offsite tools for this?

Comment: @P.Mort.-forgotClayShirky_q We've had a couple of "spin-off" sites founded on the idea that SE isn't the most suitable platform for us, and I believe one of them (no longer in development) toyed with the idea, but I'm not aware of any tools or similar that works on this. We've developed a site culture about accepting the winning answer, but that doesn't always work, especially with newer users

Comment: They have [apparently done it at Codidact](https://meta.codidact.com/posts/283884) (near *"integrated into the community"*), including making it official/integrated already.

Answer (score 6):

### "It looks like you're asking a question about Scrum. Have you considered asking it on [Project Management](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) instead?"

(Maybe a bit less Clippy-esque though. *Maybe*.)

I remember back when we were in beta, the only thing stopping us from graduating was #questions/day.

We continue to suffer from relatively few new questions.

Further, I remember coming upon several questions (one of them even a HNQ) on [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) and thinking 'This is a textbook pmse question'.

So, the same way that the site looks at your tags/content and shows possible duplicates, could we set it up to show 'Hey it looks like this question is better-suited to this smaller, more niche site over here'?

The idea could presumably be extended to other smaller sites, as well. Even Software Engineering itself could benefit from having certain questions/questioners nudged to it from Stack Overflow.

Comment: Like the question asking wizard? :D.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Yeah. Just including a cross-site suggestion to it.

Comment: Or should we get rid of niche sites, in favour of bigger sites all together? For example the gazillion bitcoin like sites, they could just as well do with one site for all of them.

Comment: That would need very careful consideration and such. While I don't really like having that many cryptocurrency sites, there's a lot of sites with overlapping scope and distinctive cultures

Comment: Agreed @JourneymanGeek, but at the same time, a lot of people are familiar with a certain site, and hence ask their question, which is (borderline) on-topic, there rather then on a obscure small network site they haven't interacted with before. Nudging, or guiding them there, then might have an adverse effect. Especially when on a smaller site it might take longer to get an answer. Then who has really benefited from OP asking their question on a small site.

Comment: @Luuklag "Especially when on a smaller site it might take longer to get an answer." I was thinking the exact opposite. Yeah there are way more *users* on SE than on pmse, but there are more pm-experts on pmse than on SE.

Comment: @Sarov true, you are more likely to get an excellent answer on pm.SE then on any other site. But you might get a decent answer on a different site quicker, which would allow you to continue on with the problem at hand. Its almost compared to learning for a test. Do you learn to remember things for the rest of your life, or do you learn to pass your test. If the latter is the case, you might be better off at a bigger site.

Comment: @Luuklag Maybe. I'm not so sure I agree, but uncertain enough to concede the point. Still, I strongly suspect most pm-related questions were asked on SE because the OPs didn't know pmse existed. Plus, it would (presumably) be set up as a guidance, not a requirement.
Plus, ultimately, if smaller sites are to remain (which I assume they will), then the knowledge repository goal of Stack Exchange as a whole will benefit from stronger separation of concerns.

Comment: @Luuklag given popular view on [urgency matters](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569/839601) your reasoning sounds more in favor of better quality (even if slower) answers. :) As one who gets most answers to my questions by searching (as opposed to asking) I myself am also strongly inclined to prefer thorough answers over quick-n-dirty ones

Comment: @gnat I thought that was *my* reasoning! But yeah, I agree - quality of the shared knowledge database should be our primary goal.

Comment: @Luuklag It's better to have a little bit of overlap among distinct specialized sites. Giant sites like Stack Overflow are newbie grinders. I would rather shop at a bazaar of small specialized shops with some overlap than a giant super store that carries a little bit of everything that is of adequate quality and functionality, but might not have a great quality item of the type you're looking for, or if it does, it's hard to find in the sea of mass produced junk.

Comment: @ColleenV "..it's hard to find in the sea of mass produced junk." I kind of agree, although it's all a bit artificial (the division into sub-SEs as well as the combination of them). I have accounts on at least 50 if not 100 Exchanges. In principle I don't care where my questions get answered as long as they get answered.

Comment: @Trilarion You don’t care about the quality of the answer or whether it’s correct, so long as you get one? Any native English speaker can answer half of the “is this sentence correct?” questions on ELL; few of them can explain why it’s correct. There are many questions where the commonly held belief is simply wrong. If you don’t ask your question where the experts are, you are less likely to get a good answer and its  score is more likely to reflect its  popularity than its credibility.

Comment: @ColleenV No, I want the highest possible quality answer, but I don't care on which Exchange it will be posted really. In principle, from the perspective of an asker, you can move my question freely to wherever you want as long as it maximizes the chances that I get the best possible help (in both quantity and quality). Yes, I have to choose an Exchange in the beginning, but I don't really really care about this choice, I only want answers.

Comment: @Trilarion Wouldn’t you want your question in the place where it had the best chance of getting a high quality answer? You’re contradicting yourself when you say “I don’t care where it’s posted, but I care whether it gets a high quality answer.” The entire pint of the comment you responded to was that specialized sites are better at providing high quality answers to high quality questions. I’m not sure I understand why you think whether or not you care what site your question gets answered on is relevant.

Comment: @ColleenV Sorry for the misunderstanding. I just wanted to say that I have lots of accounts on many Exchanges and I'm completely open to ask on any of them and see the differentiation as somewhat artificial. Indeed I'm only interested in highest quality answers and if you are right and they can indeed by found at specialized Exchanges then I'm more than willing to go there. Just tell me where to go and I'll do it. If you can actually move questions around and do that for me, all the better for it, I have nothing against it. But it has to result in the best possible answers.

Comment: @Trilarion I really have to stop trying to use analogies to explain things. They never seem to do a great job, but for some reason I can’t resist using them. I would like to see the [cross-site search](https://stackexchange.com/) get more visibility. I don’t think most users know it’s there. It should be a lot quicker to get an answer if your question has already been asked, but if you’re searching the wrong site, you might not find it. I want a way to expand a site search to more sites if I didn’t find any results that were helpful in my first search.

Comment: @ColleenV Your link just goes to HNQ?

Comment: @Sarov The search box at the top of the page goes across all sites.

Comment: @ColleenV Ahh. Wow yeah that's pretty hidden, innit? From what I remember from studying UI in university, that means the designers don't really want us to use the feature. Like how you make the hard-delete button hard to find, if for some reason you need one. :P

Comment: There’s a some logic to it… it treats the entire “network” a little like a single site so the search box on any ‘network’ page searches the entire site. For example, you can also get to that search from your network profile. It’s just that few people think about the network as a whole and just focus on their favorite sites.

Comment: @ColleenV You can tell just from the name of the tab ("Hot Questions - Stack Exchange"), that the UI wants to draw attention towards the HNQ, not to the 'this is the general site page' aspect, though.

Comment: It’s hidden in plain sight. We get used to seeing a search bar at the top of every page so we don’t really “see” it unless we are looking to use it. We don’t go looking for the “search all sites” because we don’t know the feature exists, and the network pages are a mishmash of design elements. Some elements are similar to single site features and some are unique to network pages and what sorts of tasks you would go to those pages for is not intuitive. They feel like “trivia” pages with interesting random tidbits of information instead of where you would go to accomplish something useful.

Comment: @ColleenV Yep. Something like a toggle on the site-specific searches, maybe. When you click on the box, it shows "Search on Project Management" plus "Search on all Sites" (or, context-specific, "Search on Project Management Meta" plus "Search on all Meta Sites").

Comment: @ColleenV Thanks for the explanation. Yes, cross-site search sounds perfect.

Answer (score 5):

If my magic wand had enough power left after my first suggestion, I would change the way questions are tagged on ELL. I'd rather just wave a wand and make more people care about tagging questions well, but mind manipulation is an evil sort of magic we should probably avoid.

First, I would create a system that analyzes the text of the question, looks at similar questions with high scores or that have been edited to update their tags then suggests tags that might be appropriate. Under no circumstances would it suggest a tag because it was "popular". (I have no idea how to actually implement this, I'm relying on magic here.)

I would give a community a way to exclude tags from being suggested. English Language Learners has this terrible "grammar" tag that gets applied to questions regardless of whether or not they are actually about grammar (as opposed to "grammaticality"). A while back, [we had reduced the number of questions tagged only with "grammar" to about 300 or so](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3332/9161) today, [there are over 3400 open questions with just the grammar tag](https://data.stackexchange.com/ell/query/580996/nonclosed-questions-with-only-the-grammar-tag).

If someone asking a question really can't pick appropriate tags, there should be a "can't-decide" or "don't-know" tag that puts it into a review queue to be tagged properly and we should give people badges and such for participating in the queue. If someone doesn't know the answer to their question, often they don't know the best way to categorize it so that it is grouped with similar questions (at least on sites like ELL where something can look like a question about one thing but actually be about something [Linguists are still arguing about](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/117193/9161) ). Maybe there are other things that would trigger a review, like someone creating a new tag, the question being closed as a duplicate that has different tags, or the question getting put on the HNQ.

Answer (score 5):

#### Ability to search Species ID posts using pictures

*(copied from [Redesigning **Biology Stack Exchange** (extended)](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3652/16866) on Biology Meta)*

**Problem:**

Most people coming to Biology SE to have their unknown specimen identified have two options: either browse through dozens (or hundreds) of old posts to see if they can find a match for their specimen, or (much more commonly) just ask a new question.

- This first option requires opening each post individually, and therefore is incredibly time consuming. As a result, most users opt for option 2.
- This is ok if it's in fact a new species (i.e., one not previously ID'd on Bio.SE before) or if one of our users can recognize it as a duplicate of a previous post.

  - However, with 600+ species ID posts, there is a good chance that there are un-marked duplicate posts.

**Proposal:**

Wouldn't it be so much better if you could sort through old [species-identificaion](/questions/tagged/species-identificaion) posts by **picture**?

I have no idea how this could be done (and I'm fairly sure it actually *cannot* be done), but it would make our species ID posts *MUCH* more accessible to visiting users.

- This would likely result in heavier traffic through the site.

Here's an example of how I think this could be done:

[image]

How this could work:

- I envision one of 2 ways:

  1. Auto selects 1st image in a post
  2. Provide some ability for a user to select which image to include in search.

Comment: Not very likely, but I always thought it'd be a cool/useful tool. You could add a toggle to allow people to turn pictures on or off. Anyway, I could envision it being helpful on many sites other than Biology, too.

Comment: It sounds like a good project for an intern at Stack Overflow (machine learning). It could also lead to other interesting features, like a search bot, conversation bot (e.g., to pry out question details), or auto answer bot.

Comment: Just license and use Google lens to be used before asking on this Exchange? Basically Biology should have a requirement that users use other available resources first, before asking for human evaluation. It looks very similar to posting duplicate coding questions on SO.

Comment: @Trilarion Google lens is unfortunately not an adequate, appropriate, or accurate choice of tools. The biggest issue is that it gives an answer and the user has no way to know if it's accurate (hint: it often isn't). On SE, you've got multiple biologists putting eyes on ID. I'm not concerned about them asking. The issue of this post is not that they *are* asking, but rather that they could learn from already well-written posts if they had a way to search using the info they have: visual.

Comment: @Philippe, what ever became of these ideas/efforts??

Answer (score 5):

## Ask Ubuntu

---

Posted by [C.S.Cameron](https://meta.askubuntu.com/users/43926/c-s-cameron) [here](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/19732).

> ### Obsolete Answer Flag
>
> In many cases the answer with the most upvotes is simply the one that has been here longest. Often these high vote answers are totally obsolete and no longer work.
>
> It was much easier to get votes in the old days, when Ask Ubuntu was new and unique. Answers did not need to be very good to get lots of upvotes.
>
> There should be an **obsolete flag** so that users can flag these old and obsolete answers to drop them from the top of the list. A flagged answer does not need to be totally removed, just dropped to the bottom of the page where it won't hurt anyone. It should probably take a vote of five flags to demote an answer.
>
> Closing a duplicate question and then linking an old question with 20 obsolete answers wastes the users time and does not give users much confidence in Ask Ubuntu.
>
> Some people talk about historical value of these answers but people come here to get help making their Ubuntu work, not history lessons.
>
> Lets keep Ask Ubuntu relevant and up to date.

Answer (score 4):

### Making all users use the [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?answertab=active) before posting a challenge on [Code Golf and Coding Challenges](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/)

We often get questions from new users that are duplicates, are not specified clearly enough, have problems that take the fun out of them, or are simply off-topic, and posting drafts in the Sandbox for Proposed Challenges first helps reduce that a bit. Users are asked to use the Sandbox, but it's not enforced at all.

For this reason, it'd be amazing if, before posting a question not tagged with [tips](/questions/tagged/tips), a user would be required to submit a link to an answer in the Sandbox that's at least a day old as proof that they've sandboxed their question and gotten reviews on it before posting it. Of course, it's possible to get around this by adding the link to someone else's answer if you want to abuse the system, but if the user in question is acting in good faith, this feature ensures that their question gets at least a little bit of reviewing. That way, we can reduce the number of questions that get closed.

It'd be even better to have a tool to migrate questions from the Sandbox to the main site directly, but of course, that's probably asking for too much.

Comment: I think there's better ways to handle this. I'm not really sure what exactly those would be, but requiring using the sandbox (especially with a system as hacky as this) sounds like a bad idea. ([Discussion](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/conversation/discussion-on-rquiring-sandboxing))

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms Worldbuilding also has a sandbox and I'd *love* if more people used it. I do agree it's hacky. Perhaps there is a case to be made for a better type of sandbox.

Comment: @VLAZ I 100% would support an official solution for sandboxing, something like a `sandbox.[xyz].stackexchange.com` or even just a way to mark a meta question as a sandbox and give it some extra features. Considering writing an answer here about sandboxing in general.

Answer (score 4):

I would want the magic wand to decrease the limit of simultaneous hot questions from the same site from 5 to 3 or 4, in order to give more sites the chance to be advertised to a network-wide audience. The last time I asked for statistics about this, it looked [somewhat depressing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/347147/165773), even with outliers ignored:

> 86 least represented sites of 156 total contributed less than 10% hot questions, 106 contributed less than 20% questions and 135 - less than 50% questions. 21 top sites of 156 contributed over 50% hot questions...

The result I would expect to obtain is a more diverse representation of various sites in the hot list. As for knowing the difference, in this case it seems to be fairly easy, because there is a way to estimate the presence of the site and compare results to prior statistics referred to above.

The longer term impact I would be hoping to achieve is a noticeable growth of the active user base at smaller sites, indicated by the amount of users with a reasonably solid on-site reputation (not counting the association bonus).

---

Preferably the above would be augmented by disabling a tweak that pushes Stack Overflow questions from the hot list a bit too strong. This would serve the same purpose as above: a more prominent presence of SO questions in hot list would help the major audience of this list realise that [smaller sites aren't something alien](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/397231/839601) and that they are welcome to participate in these sites just like they do at Stack Overflow.

The results I would want to get by this change are the same as above: a noticeable growth of the active user base at smaller sites.

As for knowing the difference, it would be a bit complicated. There is a natural and straightforward measure by simply counting the active users who joined some site when they already had an SO account. However, it would cover only part of the picture because some anonymous SO visitors may join sites they have seen in the hot list without creating an SO account - and I haven't yet figured how this can be estimated.

---

I won't hazard a guess whether my beliefs would be widely shared or not, because [the hot questions are a blessing and a curse](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/a/1247/516).

Comment: FWIW, these features likely [already exist](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/316904/which-sites-are-excluded-or-limited-from-hot-network-questions) (both the capping [IPS], and the "hotness" adjustments [SO, Soft.Eng., TWP]). Fingers crossed they're easily configurable and fingers double crossed they can make the limits and thresholds dynamic rather than static.

Comment: @Nick looks like they are indeed: "This number is also configurable on a per-site basis, so if a site wants to reduce their HNQ footprint, we can lower it even more, even to zero if a site wishes to be excluded entirely..." ([from this announcement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/325060/165773))

Comment: Coming from a site where 90% of all questions manage to game the HNQ algorithm, I agree with this.

Comment: As a mod from a smaller site, I'm in two minds about this -- sometimes it seems we appear in HNQ because it's [buggin's turn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buggins%27_turn) and I can't remember when we were last happy with the publicity -- good questions around our neck of the woods (needing expertise to answer) are not HNQ material; HNQ (hot) questions are trivial and easily answered. I wouldn't want buggin's turn to come around more often.  I'd much prefer a mechanism where the community nominated candidates for HNQ and *then* the algorithm ran to share the capacity around.

Comment: @ColeValleyGirl agree, you have good reasons to be concerned. And you're not alone - ask for example Math.SE mods how many questions they have to manually remove from HNQ. Sad to see this happening to feature that is in theory supposed to be desired and beneficial to all involved. Guess that't the price to pay for negligence - most of HNQ settings which make it troublesome haven't been touched since ancient times when whole SE network was, like, 4-5 techical sites and very hot list was buried in [small dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wtvfh.png) under an obscure button in the top bar

Answer (score 4):

## Multimedia Help Center

> If I had to choose a different site from my previous post, let's say that this is about Meta Stack Exchange, but I think that this might apply to all the sites, including per-site metas.

Nowadays the content of the Help Center only contains text articles. Some of these articles include links to meta posts, the company blog posts and external content that might look not very attractive because of their format and length, specially for "new users". I would like the magic wand to add multimedia elements to all the articles so they become more attractive and easy to understand by *a broader audience* (not all users learn the same way).

These multimedia elements could be material developed by the community, short clips took from the company podcast, YouTube videos, etc.

P.S. I would love to see a Stack Exchange board game.

Comment: Personally I like text much much better than fancy multimedia stuff; it's quicker and easier to get to the information I want, or describe to others how to get there. I actively avoid videos when searching for "how to"s, rules, etc. But I know other people like videos more - just saying that I would be disappointed if there was important stuff hidden behind videos or audio.

Comment: This "magic wand wish" is to add, not to replace. Anyway, if for any reason there are some original content in video/audio, I would like that they include a transcript.

Comment: I like this idea, a lot of new users are probably under professional/academic pressure when they join the site. Reading a *"wall of text"* in the help center is likely to hit them like a brick. Multimedia doesn't solve everything, but it can make things easier for some users. Not everyone learns the same way.

Comment: So, let's take one of those help center pages that mods can edit, the help/on-topic page. How would this look like in multimedia? I know youtube clips lend themselves well to 'click here, then there' types of instructions, but how would a youtube clip teach people about what's on/off-topic on a site?

Comment: @Tinkeringbell I hope that the magic wand is wise enough to decide what kind of multimedia resource be good to help to understand each help article. Some sites might include a quiz about the core concepts required to understand the on-topic/off-topic, i.e. if a user don't know intuitively the difference between a web app and a native app or between using and developing one, very hardly they will understand what is on-topic / off-topic on Web Applications. The quiz might point point them to a material that explains that.

Comment: @Tinkeringbell it would be exactly like [this Davie504 vid](https://youtu.be/BRUr0c9lL9o?t=408). Slap now! Epic!!

Comment: What about a small clip like symbol that explains the rules and sits in a top corner of every page? Occasionally it could also give useful tips and hints. Something like: "If you are asking a question, don't forget to google it before asking and don't forget to include a summary of the search results in your question.". If it only works in 10% of the cases, it would be a great improvement.

Comment: @Trilarion Are you suggesting Clippy? (related suggestion from 2009 -> https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/27829/289691? :) What if instead of a clip, the symbol is a flying waffle, a toasted unicorn or a colorful hat ?

Comment: @Rubén Whatever works best, but clippy has a certain nostalgic appeal.

Answer (score 3):

## Shared Drive for valuable Google spreadsheets

The top tag in Web Applications is [google-sheets](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-sheets), many posts having this tag have links to Google spreadsheets that are shared with anyone with the link to view or to edit. Sometimes that is the best way to show what the OP tried or to help others to reproduce the problem and propose a solution, but over the time the spreadsheets are moved to the trash or deleted. Now that Google have changed the policy for Google Drive storage the risk to loss valuable spreadsheets is bigger.

It would be nice if there is a Shared Drive "owned" by Web Applications were the users with certain privilege level could add Google spreadsheets there. Some sort of [Wayback Machine - Internet Archive](https://archive.org/web/) but for questions' and answers' valuable Google spreadsheets.

I think that it's feasible in the short term that a Community Manager having a Google Workspace account create a Shared Drive and add the Web Applications moderators as Contributors. Then the community could flag the posts having a valuable spreadsheet to be added to the Shared Drive.

Later this could be extended to other tags, starting with other Google Workspace Editors (documents, drawings, forms, presentations) and supported files from third party web applications.

P.S. Stack Overflow also has a `google-sheets` tag with an large number of posts having links to Google spreadsheets.

Comment: Hasn't SE's introduction of support for tables solved this to some extent? (Google has been known for discontinuing services, the last example that affected SE was [*Goodbye, Prettify. Hello highlight.js*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/353983)). So relying on external services might cause the entire tag to be discontinued without warning at some point.

Comment: @bad_coder Unfortunately not for most of posts about Google Sheets. In this case the tag is about the external service, if it disappears the tag becomes irrelevant, anyway, let ask the magic wand to make the external service to be perpetual.

Answer (score 1):

## Ask Ubuntu

---

Posted by [user535733](https://meta.askubuntu.com/users/19626/user535733) [here](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/19690).

> **Better integration with other forms of Ubuntu documentation.**
>
> Many of the questions that we answer are already addressed in documentation.
>
> But those answers are hard to find, hard to understand for some audiences, of varying quality, and spread among a dozen places I can think of.
>
> So we wind up duplicating a bunch of it here. And then both the original location and the answer here slowly rot, both minimally-maintained and both hard to find.
>
> **I would use the magic wand** to make the 10 minutes I spend writing an answer ALSO incrementally improve the existing documentation and make that improved documentation easier to find.
>
> As a consequence, we would have better documentation that's updated (instead of languishing), more understandable by a wider audience, and every AskUbuntu answer becomes a more effective contribution to the Ubuntu community.
>
> I realize that's a tall order, and I don't claim to fully see the path to get there from here. Good thing it's a *magic* wand.

Comment: As Philippe mentioned he will also read the other post, cross-posting is hardly necessary I think.

Answer (score -3):

I'd like to have the inverse of the existing **Convert Answer to Comment** function.

Users post answers in comments for several reasons - they can't be voted down, or the answer is not fleshed out enough.  Or simple error.

I'd prefer to see that proto-answer moved from comments to Answers, where it can be edited and improved by a wider range of site-users.

The only option now is to delete the comment, which leaves the whole post diminished, especially if that was a valid point, or worse if it was the only answer.

Yes I know there's nothing stopping me swiping the point and posting an answer, but that doesn't build community and rep for the original commenter.

***tl-dr***:   Please can we have "Convert comment to answer" functionality.

Comment: "*that doesn't build community and rep for the original commenter.*" counter-point - the original commented maybe doesn't *want* rep. I'd often post a comment when I don't think the question is useful to remain as a public Q&A. E.g., it was a typo on OP's part and I close voted it as such but also comment to tell them how to fix it. What I *don't* want is answers being posted and a useless question remaining around. What I especially don't want is me answering it. And receiving rep for an answer to a question *I do not want*, doesn't feel really good.

Comment: Counterpoint: since one of the differences between comments and answers is that wrong comments can't be downvoted, converting some comments to answers would cause their creators to *lose* reputation. Better to suggest that the comment author convert to an answer on their own, or paste the comment as a blockquote into a community-wiki answer.

Comment: @VLAZ I don't get it - if you're posting an answer, its an answer and goes in the answers.  By posting an answer in the comments, you're setting a bad example.  Some SE sites would simply delete the comment, but this requested function would instead save it.

Comment: @Criggie [we have a close reason for typos on SO](https://i.imgur.com/l2gUkGQ.png). We have it because *we do not want to answer these questions and keep them around*. I ***beg of you***, please do not answer them. They are not useful for future visitors. I write a comment to still aid the question asker in fixing it while still leaving the question free to be removed when it is no longer needed.

Comment: @VLAZ we must be talking at cross-purposes then.  These comments aren't improving the answer, so we should stop.

Comment: I would definitely love for mods to be able to have this! There's so many situations where our users and mods had to spend so much effort trying to get people to convert comments to answers!

Comment: Yes please, sometimes everyone answers questions in comments!